# how can I vectorize setting the index values to one in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I have the following loop that does what I need:

```
> whos Y
  Name       Size               Bytes  Class     Attributes

   Y         10x5000            400000  double              

> whos y
   Name         Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

   y         5000x1             40000  double              

Y = zeros(K,m);
for i=1:m
    Y(y(i),i)=1;
end
```

I would like to vectorize it and I have tried without success e.g.

```
Y = zeros(K,m);
Y(y,:)=1;
```

The idea is to get a vector of:

```
y = [9, 8, 7, .. etc]
```

and convert it to:

```
Y = [[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]' [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]' [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]' ... etc]
```

this I need in the context of a multi-class ANN implementation.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12658682/802117

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using sparse matrix?

```
n=numel(y);
Y = sparse( y, 1:n, 1, n, n );
```

If you really must have the full matrix, you can call

```
Y = full(Y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution you could use.  It's a starting point from which you could optimise

```
k = 10;
n = 20;
y = randi(k, 1, n);

columns = 1:n;
offsets = k*(columns-1);
indices = offsets + y;

Y = zeros(k, n);
Y(indices) = 1
```