# Matlab: Convert elements larger (smaller) than 1 (-1) into a sequence of 1 (-1)

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization

**UPDATE:** I've done some testing, and the solution of Jonas is the fastest for a range of different size input vectors. In particular, as angainor points out, the solution scales up to large sizes incredibly well - an important test as it is usually the large size problems that prompt us to pose these kind of questions on SO. Thanks to both Jonas and tmpearce for your solutions - based on the efficiency of the solution for large size problems I'm giving the answer tick to Jonas.

**My Question:** I have this column vector:

```
Vec = [0; 1; 2; -1; -3; 0; 0; 2; 1; -1];
```

I would like to convert every element greater than one into a sequence of ones that has length equal to the value of the element. Similarly, I want to convert every element less than minus one into a sequence of minus ones. Thus my output vector should look like this:

```
VecLong = [0; 1; 1; 1; -1; -1; -1; -1; 0; 0; 1; 1; 1; -1];
```

Note that each 2 has been changed into two 1's, while the -3 has been changed into three -1's. Currently, I solve the problem like this:

```
VecTemp = Vec;
VecTemp(VecTemp == 0) = 1;
VecLong = NaN(sum(abs(VecTemp)), 1);
c = 1;
for n = 1:length(Vec)
    if abs(Vec(n)) <= 1
        VecLong(c) = Vec(n);
        c = c + 1;
    else
        VecLong(c:c + abs(Vec(n))) = sign(Vec(n));
        c = c + abs(Vec(n));
    end    
end
```

This doesn't feel very elegant. Can anyone suggest a better method? Note: You can assume that `Vec` will contain only integer values. Thanks in advance for all suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the good old cumsum-approach to repeating the entries properly. Note that I'm assigning a few temporary variables that you can get rid of, if you want to put everything into one line.

```
%# create a list of values to repeat
signVec = sign(Vec);

%# create a list of corresponding indices that repeat
%# as often as the value in signVec has to be repeated

tmp = max(abs(Vec),1); %# max: zeros have to be repeated once
index = zeros(sum(tmp),1);
index([1;cumsum(tmp(1:end-1))+1])=1; %# assign ones a pivots for cumsum
index = cumsum(index); %# create repeating indices

%# repeat
out = signVec(index);
out'
out =

     0     1     1     1    -1    -1    -1    -1     0     0     1     1     1    -1
```

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't working for me on R2012b. The first problem is the second argument to the `sign` and `abs` function. Am I missing something here? My understanding is that both those functions only accept one argument (and certainly R2012b throws an error for me with two input arguments).

Comment: @ColinTBowers: My bad - I've copied the line with the wrong parenthesis. Now everything runs just fine.

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry, I probably should have been able to spot that myself. Works nicely and runs faster than the loop (+1) - thanks very much Jonas. I'll wait overnight before choosing an answer in case anyone else wants a crack at it.

Comment: This one looks rather perfect. @Colin, try it for a larger system size. It is almost 10 times faster than your loop. Although you could rework your loop a bit..

Comment: @angainor Closer to 20 times faster on my machine :-) Definitely worth the answer tick! Unless the solution is trivial, I just like to wait 24 hours before giving the tick so all the time-zones get a chance to have a crack at a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Edit: I thought of another (slightly obscure) but shorter way to do this, and it is faster than the loop you've got.

```
for rep=1:100000
    #% original loop-based solution
end
toc
Elapsed time is 2.768822 seconds.

#% bsxfun-based indexing alternative
tic;
for rep=1:100000
TempVec=abs(Vec);TempVec(Vec==0)=1;
LongVec = sign(Vec(sum(bsxfun(@gt,1:sum(TempVec),cumsum(TempVec)))+1))
end
toc
Elapsed time is 1.798339 seconds.
```

This answer scales pretty well too, compared to the original - at least, to a point.  There's a performance sweet spot.

```
Vec = repmat(OrigVec,10,1);
#% test with 100,000 loops
#% loop-based solution:
Elapsed time is 19.005226 seconds.
#% bsxfun-based solution:
Elapsed time is 4.411316 seconds.

Vec = repmat(OrigVer,1000,1);
#% test with 1,000 loops - 100,000 would be horribly slow
#% loop-based solution:
Elapsed time is 18.105728 seconds.
#% bsxfun-based solution:
Elapsed time is 98.699396 seconds.
```

bsxfun is expanding the vector into a matrix, then collapsing it with sum.  With very large vectors this is needlessly memory heavy compared to the loop, so it ends up losing.  Before then though, it does quite well.

---

Original, slow answer:

Here's a one-liner:

```
out=cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) repmat(((x>0)*2)-1+(x==0),max(1,abs(x)),1),Vec,'uni',0));
out' =

     0   1   1   1  -1  -1  -1  -1   0   0   1   1   1  -1
```

What's going on:

```
((x>0)*2)-1 + (x==0) #% if an integer is >0, make it a 1, <0 becomes -1, 0 stays 0 

max(1,abs(x)) #% figure out how many times to replicate the value  

arrayfun(@(x) (the above stuff), Vec, 'uni', 0) #% apply the function  
 #% to each element in the array, generating a cell array output

cell2mat( (the above stuff) ) #% convert back to a matrix
```

Comment: Note: if you use something like this, write some comments in the code explaining what it does!

Comment: The one-liner is admittedly much cleaner looking - but over an order of magnitude slower on my machine! (no doubt attributable to the extra overhead associated with cell-arrays)

Comment: Yup... `arrayfun` is slow too.  Loops are often much faster than `arrayfun` or `cellfun`, and sometimes quite competitive with even better vectorized solutions, especially if preallocation (like you've done) is properly done.  They just get a bad rap.  One-liners are fun though, especially if the speed isn't crucial :)

Comment: Ha! Funny you should say that - if you want a good read on `arrayfun` versus loops, check out the great answer provided by angainor to one of my other SO questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why), ps I've +1'ed your answer, but I'm afraid I can't award the answer tick given the speed issue

Comment: I'm afraid the new solution doesn't work. Check element 11, it is a 0 when it should be a 1?

Comment: Doh, you're right.  I just fixed it, for future reference (since it sounds like Jonas's answer works well and is quite fast)

Comment: No worries, thanks for the fix, and thanks for the solutions. I've given the answer tick to Jonas though, as the solution provided by Jonas scales incredibly well to large input vectors.