# How to apply a function to each row of a matrix and get back a larger matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a function that accepts a matrix of dimension [1,2] and returns a matrix of dimensions [1,136]. I also have a matrix of dimensions [N,2]. I want to apply this function to each row of the matrix to finally get a matrix of dimensions [N,136].

I am completely lost on how to do this in Matlab. A for loop solution would be enough (I can't even do that at this point), but as far as I know in Matlab there are better and more parallelizable ways of doing things.

My current attempt looks like this:

```
  phi = arrayfun(@(x,y) gaussianBasis([x y])' , trainIn(:,1), trainIn(:,2), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

where `gaussianBasis` is a function returning a vector [136,1] and `trainIn` is a matrix [N,2]. `phi` is supposed to be [N,136], but this returns an array of N cell arrays each containing a matrix [1,136].

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @yoda is spot on (+1). As you suggest in the question, it may also be possible to vectorize your function `gaussianBasis` to accept an N*2 input. If possible, this should run faster than the `arrayfun` approach, since `arrayfun` is [often slower than an explicit loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why). Of course, to determine if your function can be vectorized, we'd need to actually see it. Cheers.

Comment: Yoda's solution worked for me. I don't have to parallelize anything yet and I actually think I might have made a mistake while implementing `gaussianBasis`. OS maybe that will be my next question later. Thanks :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use `cat` and concatenate it along the first dimension:

```
phi = cat(1, phi{:})
```

This should give you an N x 136 matrix