# Matlab: How to update struct fields "in place" using struct fun?

Tags: matlab

I have a structure

```
s.a = [1 2 3];
s.b = [2 3 4 5];
s.c = [9, 6 ,3];
s.d = ... % etc. - you got the gist of it
```

Now I want to apply a function/operation on the data stored in each field and **modify** the content of the field, that is I want to apply

```
s.a = myFun( s.a );
s.b = myFun( s.b );
s.c = myFun( s.c ); % etc. ...
```

How can I do it without explicitly write all the fields as above?
I was thinking of `structfun` - but I'm not so sure how to accomplish this "in place" modification...

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the impatient reader, the `structfun` solution is at the bottom of my answer :-) But I would first ask myself...

What's wrong with using a loop? The following example shows how it can be done:

```
%# An example structure
S.a = 2;
S.b = 3;

%# An example function
MyFunc = @(x) (x^2);

%# Retrieve the structure field names
Names = fieldnames(S);

%# Loop over the field-names and apply the function to each field
for n = 1:length(Names)
    S.(Names{n}) = MyFunc(S.(Names{n}));
end
```

Matlab functions such as `arrayfun` and `cellfun` typically [are slower than an explicit loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why). I'm guessing `structfun` probably suffers from the same problem, so why bother?

However, if you insist on using `structfun` it can be done as follows (I made the example a little more complicated just to emphasize the generality):

```
%# structfun solution
S.a = [2 4];
S.b = 3;
MyFunc = @(x) (x.^2);
S = structfun(MyFunc, S, 'UniformOutput', 0);
```

Comment: Very interesting point regarding the runtime of `cellfun` and `arrayfun`. I am still more inclined toward `structfun` because I feel it is more "elegant" than loop. I also think it contributes to the readability of the code. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @Shai Fair enough. I've updated my answer to include a `structfun` solution. If you think I've answered the question, then feel free to click the tick mark. Otherwise, let me know and perhaps I can improve it. Cheers :-)