# Call multiple functions from cells in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cell-array, function-handle

I store some functions in cell, e.g. `f = {@sin, @cos, @(x)x+4}`.

Is it possible to call all those functions at the same time (with the same input). I mean something more efficient than using a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As constructed, the `*fun` family of functions exists for this purpose (e.g., [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) is the pertinent one here).  They are other questions on the [use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16143314/matlab-arrayfun-cellfun-spfun-and-structfun-vs-simple-for-loop) and [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15851718/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-perform-arithmetic-operations-on-each-element-of-a-ce) of these functions.

However, if you construct `f` as a function that constructs a cell array as

```
f = @(x) {sin(x), cos(x), x+4};
```

then you can call the function more naturally: `f([1,2,3])` for example.
This method also avoids the need for the (`'UniformOutput'`,`false`) option pair needed by `cellfun` for non-scalar argument.

You can also use regular double arrays, but then you need to be wary of input shape for concatenation purposes: `@(x) [sin(x), cos(x), x+4]` vs. `@(x) [sin(x); cos(x); x+4]`.

Comment: Nice =) +1! I provided some benchmarking results that show that your approach is indeed fast (and that loops aren't that slow)! =)

Answer (score 3):

I'm just posting these benchmarking results here, just to illustrate that loops not necessarily are slower than other approaches:

```
f = {@sin, @cos, @(x)x+4};
x = 1:100;
tic
for ii = 1:1000
    for jj = 1:numel(f)
        res{jj} = f{jj}(x);
    end
end
toc

tic
for ii = 1:1000
    res = cellfun(@(arg) arg(x),functions,'uni',0);
end
toc

Elapsed time is 0.042201 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.179229 seconds.
```

Troy's answer is almost twice as fast as the loop approach:

```
tic
for ii = 1:1000
    res = f((1:100).');
end
toc
Elapsed time is 0.025378 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick

```
functions = {@(arg) sin(arg),@(arg) sqrt(arg)}
x = 5;
cellfun(@(arg) arg(x),functions)
```

hope this helps.

Adrien.

Comment: It works, but it's about 4 times as slow as just using regular loops.