# cut signal (interlinked) and compute theses parts

Tags: algorithm, matlab, optimization, signal-processing, nested-loops

I'm a French student engineer in signal processing field and I do my internship in a neuroscience laboratory. I've to process a lot of data from the brain activity with the help of Matlab, so one of my main subject is to optimize the code. But now I'm stuck in a situation that I can't resolve and I don't find anything about it on the web. I explain my problem :

For example the matrix a :

```
a = [ 1 2 3 4 5;  6 7 8 9 10;11 12 13 14 15]
```

Each row is the datas of a signal (so here we have 3 signals), and I want, for each signal/row, cut the vector in blcoks interlinked of the same length.

For instance for the signal 1, `S1 = [1 2 3 4 5]` I want to extract the bloc `S1_1 = [1 2 3], S1_2 = [2 3 4], and S1_3 = [3 4 5]` and compute every sub-block.

My first idea was to use nested loop like that :

```
[nrow ncol] = size(a);

for i = 1 : nrow
   for j = 4 : ncol
      sub_block = a(i, (j-3):j);
      result(i, j-3) = compute(sub_block);
   end
end
```

BUT as I said I have to process a lot of datas, so I want to avoid for-loop. I'm looking for an algorithm wich will be able to remove these for-loop but I don't know how to do...

I saw the function 'reshape' but this on give me sub-block like : `S1_1 = [1 2 3], S1_2 = [4 5 6]` I can't use it because here in the sub-block S1_2 I have the data from the signal 1 and the signal 2.

Then I saw the function 'blockproc' but I didn't really understand how it process and I'm not really convaince that this one can help me...

So, I hope you understand my problem and that you could help me or indicate me a way to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @Ziyao Wei's suggestion you could alternatively use [`im2col`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html):

```
>> S = im2col(a', [3 1])
S =

     1     2     3     6     7     8    11    12    13
     2     3     4     7     8     9    12    13    14
     3     4     5     8     9    10    13    14    15
```

Where `S(:, 3*k-2:3*k)` for `k = 1:data_rows` are the desired sub-blocks of row `k` of your data (`a`).

Answer (score 0):

Blockproc seems to be doing a block operation rather than a sliding operation. A bit of digging around gives this:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/nlfilter.html

But it seems the image processing toolbox is needed.

Also this might help:

http://dovgalecs.com/blog/matlab-sliding-window-easy-and-painless/

In general, try to search for sliding-window or convolution, and try to see if something shows up.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably find another way of doing your loop with the `arrayfun` function, but the fact is that it might not necessarily be faster [arrayfun can be significantly slower than an explicit loop in matlab. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you a lot for all your (quick) answers ! I didn't expect to get an answer so quickly !

I have the image processing toolbox and your different methods are greats ! I'll have to use the im2col because is the "slower" solution for me and I can remove one for-loop.

Thank you for your help