# How to select the second argument of a function in cellfun

Tags: matlab

I would like to split a cell array of strings and take the first output argument like the following

```
mycell={'a.1' 'b.2' 'c.3'}'
result1 = cellfun(@(x) strsplit(x,'.'),mycell,'UniformOutput',false)
result = cellfun(@(x) x{1},result1)
```

Is there a way to do the operation in one line, a.k.a specify argument 1 in the cellfun call?

Comment: I think you might be able to do this with `subsref`, as in [Subsref with cells](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18384735/5358968)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option would be to use `regexp`:

```
mycell = {'a.1' 'b.2' 'c.3'}';
result = regexp(mycell,'^[^.]+','match','once')
```

Output:

```
result =

  3×1 cell array

    'a'
    'b'
    'c'
```

Answer (score 2):

**One Line Solution**

you can use:

```
cellfun(@(x)subsref(strsplit(x,'.'),struct('type','{}','subs',{{1}})),mycell);
```

**Result**

```
ans = 
a
b
c
```