# Matlab Cell: Possible to cycle through using colon?

Tags: matlab

I have the following:

```
cellMat = cell(3,1);
cellMat{1} = rand(3);
cellMat{2} = rand(3);
cellMat{3} = rand(3);
```

and I want to loop through them and get the (1,1) element of each rand matrix. I tried...

```
cellMat{:}(1,1);
```

but I get "Bad cell reference operation". But the following...

```
cellMat{1}(1,1);
```

will return the correct value.

Is there a nice way I can get this to work? I'd really like to avoid using a for loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [cellfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) with a simple [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) to retrieve the element:

```
cellfun(@(x) x(1,1), cellMat)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid a `for` loop, you should know that using `cellfun` is essentially the same as a loop; and can even be slower (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284027/cellfun-versus-simple-matlab-loop-performance) and [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/42335-array-cellfun-vs-for-loop)).

If all the matrices in your cell array have two dimensions and the same size, as in your example, you could concatenate them along a third dimension and get the desired values easily:

```
array = cat(3,cellMat{:});
result = squeeze(array(1,1,:));
```