# Performing array operation without looping on a function involving 2 vectors

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, optimization

I have a function that takes one vector as its input, uses another function to create a derivative vector from the input, and then compares the two vectors to produce its output vector. I currently have it working with a for loop as follows:

```
function [parentIndexVec] = computeParentIndex(nameVec)

    parentNameVec = computeParentName(nameVec);
    for i=1:length(parentNameVec)
        parentIndexVec(i) = find(strcmp(nameVec, parentNameVec{i}));
    end

end
```

The `computeParentName` function essentially returns a copy of `nameVec` with its last letter removed. The cell arrays preceding the loop then appear as follows:

```
nameVec       = ''    'a'    'b'    'aa'    'ab'    'ba'    'aba'    'abb'
parentNameVec = ''    ''     ''     'a'     'a'     'b'     'ab'     'ab'
```

The goal of this function is to find the indices of where each element in `parentNameVec` appears in `nameVec`, and its output is thus as follows:

```
parentIndexVec = 1     1     1     2     2     3     5     5
```

I attempted to make a `cellfun` to accomplish this, but was unable to get it to operate as the two vectors must be compared at each point.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is there a way to do this by eliminating the loops?
2. Is it truly faster to have matrix operations rather than loops in most cases?
3. If so, does `cellfun` compare in speed to pure matrix operations or would it be as slow as a loop?

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use `ismember` to find the occurrences of the strings in `parentNameVec` within `nameVec`

   ```
   nameVec = {''    'a'    'b'    'aa'    'ab'    'ba'    'aba'    'abb'};
   parentNameVec = {''    ''     ''     'a'     'a'     'b'     'ab'     'ab'};

   [~, parentIndexVec] = ismember(parentNameVec, nameVec)
   %   1   1   1   2   2   3   5   5
   ```
2. For matrix operations, the operation is almost certainly going to be faster than the `for` loop. The differential between the two methods has decreased over time but it still exists. Unfortunately, in your examples you are using cell arrays which don't have matrix operations.
3. `cellfun` is almost always slower than a `for` loop because MATLAB's JIT compiler is better able to optimize the contents of a `for` loop. This is particularly true in newer versions of MATLAB (R2015b+) in which the execution engine was reworked and provides much better acceleration.

All of that being said, a built-in function is almost always going to be superior to your own implementation of an algorithm (for loop or otherwise) because it has been optimized by the Mathworks to yield decent performance, robust error checking, and sometimes it is implemented at a lower level.

Comment: I really appreciate the response. Exactly the function I was looking for! So, I actually already went through my other sub functions to replace `for` loops with `cellfun`, so I may have unwittingly decreased its efficiency. Can most operations completed with `cellfun` be done in a faster, matrix operation way? For example, the sub function mentioned above (`computeParentName`) uses cellfun to remove the last letter of each element from the `nameVec` cell array. Is there a simpler way to do such a thing?

Comment: @teepee It really depends upon the specifics of what operation you're trying to perform. There are a lot of operations for operating on cell arrays of strings built into MATLAB. To remove the last character I would do something like: `regexprep(nameVec, '.$', '')` which simply replaces the last character with an empty string.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought about using regex in MATLAB. Very nice that they can handle both chars and cellstr. That obviates the need for a lot of code I wrote to handle those distinctions. While I'm at it here, would you happen to know a cellstr function that returns the length of each string in the cell array? i.e.  `lengthArray = foo({'aaa' 'bb' 'a'})` which returns `[3 2 1]`?

Comment: @teepee Your best bet there is going to be `cellfun`: `cellfun(@numel, array)`

Comment: OK thanks muchly, that's what I had in there. I was hoping for something a bit better. Although, I hear that cellfun is not bad for built-in functions, as opposed to udf's (is that correct?)
My biggest issue with using cellfun is that it won't handle smoothly if it takes in a single string value instead of a cellstr. Do you have tips for handling that sort of thing?

Comment: @teepee Yes that's generally true. [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284027/cellfun-versus-simple-matlab-loop-performance) a post that details that.

Comment: Wow, that's actually quite startling, some of those findings. Apparently `cellfun(@isempty, array)` is significantly slower than `cellfun('isempty', array)` for some reason. That's an issue indeed.