# How to vectorize operations on cells?

Tags: matlab, octave, cell-array

Given `B = {"7" "8" "9"}`, I'd like to use its values as respective replacements for the ultimate elements of each cell in `A`, i.e. transform

```
A = {{1 2} {3 4} {5 6}}
```

into

```
A = {{1 "7"} {3 "8"} {5 "9"}}
```

In unvectorized form, this can be written as:

```
nn = cellfun(@numel, A)
for i = 1:numel(a)
  A{i}{nn(i)} = B{i};
end
```

All sub-cells may have the same length, but a solution for sub-cells of arbitrary length would be ideal.

The only solution I found involves making a reshaped copy of A:

```
nn = cellfun(@numel, A)      #=> 2 2 2
A2 = horzcat(A{:})           #=> {1 2 3 4 5 6}
jj = cumsum(nn)              #=> 2 4 6
[A2{jj}] = B{:}              #=> {1 "7" 3 "8" 5 "9"}
ii = [1 jj(1:end-1)+1]       #=> 1 3 5
A = cellslices(A2,ii,jj,2)   #=> {{1 "7"} {3 "8"} {5 "9"}
```

I'd have hoped something like the below would work - but it doesn't:

```
octave:1> [[A{:}]{ii}] = B{:}
error: invalid lvalue function called in expression
```

Is there a way to vectorize this operation?

Comment: If all sub-cells may have the same length you can use a matrix instead of nested cells.

Comment: You can always expect to have unvectorised code when dealing with cells. Btw `cellfun` is a one-liner wrapper for a loop. It is still a loop.

Comment: @SardarUsama It is a loop written in C++, and that makes it way faster than any octave-code loop. See [libinterp/corefcn/cellfun.cc](https://github.com/KubaO/Octave/blob/master/libinterp/corefcn/cellfun.cc)

Comment: @rahnema1 Some of the cells may have non-numeric values, and thus a matrix won't work.

Comment: You've explicitly asked for vectorisation, not avoiding a `for`/`while` loop.

Comment: In the loop you can use `A{i}{end} = B{i};`

Comment: Vectorisation isn't limited to numeric values!

Comment: @KubaOber The fact that with `cellfun` the loop is in C++ or Java rather than in Matlab code doesn't necessarily make it fast. In fact, `cellfun` is often slower than `for`; see for example [here](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/42335-array-cellfun-vs-for-loop) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284027/cellfun-versus-simple-matlab-loop-performance?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Anyway, performance results are dependent on the Matlab version

Comment: I'm not using `cellfun` to begin with :)

Answer (score 1):

As learned from the comments that you actually just want to avoid an explicit `for`/`while` loop and are okay with `cellfun` (the use of which is not vectorisation), the process can be replicated with `cellfun` as follows:

```
A = cellfun(@(k) {A{k}{1:end-1} B{k}}, num2cell(1:numel(A)), 'un', 0);
```

or with `arrayfun` as:

```
 A = arrayfun(@(k) {A{k}{1:end-1} B{k}}, 1:numel(A), 'un', 0);
```