# MATLAB cellfun vectorization slow when using function handle

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vectorization, cell

I encountered a weird bug in cell vectorization (MATLAB version R2019B).

Please consider the following minimal example, say we generate a cell array with variable length vector in each cell:

```matlab
N = 10000;
rng(1);
result = cell(N,1);
numConnect = randi(10, [N,1]); % randomly generated number of connected nodes
for i = 1:N
  result{i} = randi(N, [1, numConnect(i)]);
end
```

Now we want to retrospectively retrieve `numConnect`, i.e., the length of each cell, we can use [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html). According to this documentation, in Backward Compatibility mode, you can use string as `func` variable instead of function handle. However, there is a drastic difference in performance locally.

```matlab
tic;
nC1 = cellfun('length', result);
toc;
```

This one usually produces something like

> Elapsed time is 0.038531 seconds.

If I changed to `@` function handle:

```matlab
tic;
nC2 = cellfun(@length, result);
toc;
```

Then

> Elapsed time is 1.041925 seconds.

is normal. There is a 30x difference!

I wonder is this performance difference a bug on my local machine, or a "feature" of MATLAB `cellfun`?

Comment: My times are vastly faster than yours (100x), but I do see a 65x time difference. This is normal. There is overhead in calling a function, and there's even more overhead in calling a function through a handle. Using `cellfun` with `'length'` doesn't call a function, it just loops over elements and directly determines the length of each.

Comment: Yes, this is well known. See [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/articles/cellfun-undocumented-performance-boost), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18284028/2586922) and [here](https://medium.com/mathworks/which-way-to-compute-cellfun-or-for-loop-bfedfd4b46c0). By the way, `cellfun` is not vectorization

Comment: Thanks. I see. Kinda lost in the syntax.

Comment: I have checked in the latest version 2020a and it did not change since. Slower using the function handle.