# How to set an indexed value in a matrix based on another matrix's values

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

Say I have a matrix `A`

```
A =
 0     1     2
 2     1     1
 3     1     2
```

and another matrix `B`

```
B =
 0    42
 1    24
 2    32
 3    12
```

I want to replace each value in `A` by the one associated to it in `B`.

I would obtain

```
A =
 42     24     32
 32     24     24
 12     24     32
```

How can I do that without loops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this, but here is an short one:

```
[~,ind]=ismember(A,B(:,1));
Anew = reshape(B(ind,2),size(A))
```

If you can assume that the first column of `B` is always `0:size(B,1)-1`, then it is easier, becoming just `reshape(B(A+1,2),size(A))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
arrayfun(@(x)(B(find((x)==B(:,1)),2)),A)
```

Comment: `arrayfun` is an easy way to express a `for` loop in one line, but keep in mind that [`arrayfun` performance is not usually what you would expect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why).  Still, +1 for conciseness!

Comment: @chappjc: Thx, bookmarked. Never noticed arrayfun could be that slow.