# What is the quickest way to find and replace elements in a large matrix?

Tags: matlab

I want to find and replace numbers in a large matrix `A`. Vectors `B` and `C` have the same dimensions and contain values. Even though `A` may contain non-unique values, it has all the numbers of `B`. I want to search `A` for all values in `B` and replace them with the corresponding values in `C`.

For example, let A be a 2.5·10<sup>6</sup>×4 matrix. `B` and `C` are 1.5·10<sup>6</sup>×1 and have unique values. I've tried using the following for loop:

```
for q = 1:size(B, 1)
    A(A == B(q, 1)) = C(q, 1);
end
```

But it is very slow. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Show some example if u can.

Comment: Isn't this just like [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597737/matlab-how-to-set-an-indexed-value-in-a-matrix-based-on-another-matrixs-values/19597917#19597917) where `B` and `C` here are the two columns of `B` in the other question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most straightforward solution that comes to mind is using [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
[tf, loc] = ismember(A, B);
A(tf) = C(loc(tf));
```

Comment: Seems right to me too.  Note that `tf` is just `true(size(A))` and `loc` is the size of `A` so the answer is even simpler (`[~, loc] = ismember(A, B); A = C(loc);`).  Although I suppose I am assuming all the values in `A` are in `B`, so perhaps a more general solution is better here.  See [my answer from a couple days ago](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19597737/matlab-how-to-set-an-indexed-value-in-a-matrix-based-on-another-matrixs-values/19597917#19597917) on the same problem with differently shaped data.

Comment: Sorry, I was flipping things around.  You need `tf` in this case. Good point. +1