# optimizing nested for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, vectorization

I'm trying to optimize the performance (e.g. speed) of my code. I 'm new to vectorization and tried myself to vectorize, but unsucessful ( also try bxsfun, parfor, some kind of vectorization, etc ). Can anyone help me optimize this code, and a short description of how to do this?

```
% for simplify, create dummy data
Z = rand(250,1)
z1 = rand(100,100)
z2 = rand(100,100)

%update missing param on the last updated, thanks @Bas Swinckels and @Daniel R
j = 2;
n = length(Z);
h = 0.4;


tic
[K1, K2] = size(z1);
result = zeros(K1,K2);

for l = 1 : K1
    for m = 1: K2
        result(l,m) = sum(K_h(h, z1(l,m), Z(j+1:n)).*K_h(h, z2(l,m), Z(1:n-j)));    
    end
end

result = result ./ (n-j);
toc
```

The K_h.m function is the boundary kernel and defined as (x is scalar and y can be vector)

```
function res = K_h(h, x,y)
 res = 0;

 if ( x >= 0 & x < h)
    denominator = integral(@kernelFunc,-x./h,1);  
    res = 1./h.*kernelFunc((x-y)/h)/denominator;
 elseif (x>=h & x <= 1-h)
    res = 1./h*kernelFunc((x-y)/h);
 elseif (x > 1 - h & x <= 1)
    denominator = integral(@kernelFunc,-1,(1-x)./h);
    res = 1./h.*kernelFunc((x-y)/h)/denominator;
 else    
    fprintf('x is out of [0,1]');
    return;
 end
end
```

It takes a long time to obtain the results: \Elapsed time is 13.616413 seconds.

Thank you. Any comments are welcome.
P/S: Sorry for my lack of English

Comment: What are `j` and `n`? Constants?

Comment: and `h` ? Please use `clear all` and then try executing your code, you will notice any missing initialisation.

Comment: thanks @BasSwinckels. I have just updated. Sorry for my mistakes

Comment: thanks @DanielR. I just updated

Answer (score 0):

Some observations: it seems that `Z(j+1:n))` and `Z(1:n-j)` are constant inside the loop, so do the indexing operation before the loop. Next, it seems that the loop is really simple, every `result(l, m)` depends on `z1(l, m)` and `z2(l, m)`. This is an ideal case for the use of [arrayfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html). A solution might look something like this (untested):

```
tic

% do constant stuff outside of the loop
Zhigh = Z(j+1:n);
Zlow = Z(1:n-j);

result = arrayfun(@(zz1, zz2) sum(K_h(h, zz1, Zhigh).*K_h(h, zz2, Zlow)), z1, z2)

result = result ./ (n-j);
toc
```

I am not sure if this will be a lot faster, since I guess the running time will not be dominated by the for-loops, but by all the work done inside the `K_h` function.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I try this, but this not help improve the speed much

Comment: arrayfun is a nice technique for short code, but in many times does not increase performance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why