# Vectorize function that outputs a row using arrayfun, returning a matrix

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization

I'm using Octave and would like to vectorize a function that accepts as input a single real number and outputs a row vector of fixed length.  I understand that `arrayfun` should be able to do this from its unclear documentation. From `help arrayfun` in Octave 3.2:

> If the parameter VAL after a further string input argument
>   "UniformOutput" is set 'true' (the default), then the named
>    function FUNC must return a single element which then will be
>    concatenated into the return value and is of type matrix.
>    Otherwise, if that parameter is set to `false', then the outputs
>    are concatenated in a cell array.

It seems however that [Matlab's version is more forgiving](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html):

> [B1,...,Bm] = arrayfun(func,A1,...,An) calls the function specified by function handle func and passes elements from arrays A1,...,An, where n is the number of inputs to function func. Output arrays B1,...,Bm, where m is the number of outputs from function func, contain the combined outputs from the function calls. The ith iteration corresponds to the syntax [B1(i),...,Bm(i)] = func(A1{i},...,An{i}). The arrayfun function does not perform the calls to function func in a specific order.

It looks like this works in Matlab but not in Octave.  Am I correct that this generalization cannot be performed using `arrayfun` in Octave? Is there some more clever way to achieve this without resorting to unvectorized loops?

For reference, here is my Octave result:

> octave:5> nums
>   nums =
>
> @(c) ([c, c + 2, c + 4])
>
> octave:6> arrayfun(nums,[1,2,3])
>   error: cellfun: expecting all values to be scalars for UniformOutput = true
>   error: called from:
>   error:   /opt/local/share/octave/3.2.4/m/general/arrayfun.m at line 168, column 21
>   octave:6>

Comment: why do you insist on `arrayfun`? try simple `for` loop and be done with it.

Comment: @Shai http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(parallel_computing)

Comment: @djechlin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why

Comment: @DanielR that answer is for Matlab and the OP has explicitly stated he's using Octave. Advising him to use a for loop there is no no.

Answer (score 3):

Use arrayfun to apply the function, `nums` to an array `[1,2,3]`

```
CellArray = arrayfun(nums, [1,2,3], "UniformOutput", false);
```

That gives you a cell array. If you want the answer in a matrix, use `cell2mat`

```
cell2mat(CellArray);
```

If your actual `nums` is more complicated, then we'll need a better example of it to suggest a solution.

Comment: `arrayfun` with `"UniformOutput", false` returns a "row" cell array (i.e. along the 2nd dimension). And the outputs  of `nums` are also row vectors (i.e. along the 2nd dimension too). The `cell2mat` concatenates them as a long row vector.
To obtain a matrix, first reshape the cell array to be along the expected concatenation dimension: `cell2mat( reshape(CellArray, numel(CellArray), 1) )`

Comment: You can also simply transpose the vector `arrayfun(nums, [1,2,3].', "UniformOutput", false);` to have a column cell array. Note the transpose of [1,2,3]!

Answer (score 1):

The error already suggests how to solve the problem:

```
arrayfun(nums,[1,2,3],'UniformOutput',false)
```

There is no difference between Matlab and Octave.

Matlab:

```
>> nums=@(c) ([c, c + 2, c + 4])

nums = 

    @(c)([c,c+2,c+4])

EDU>> arrayfun(nums,[1,2,3])
Error using arrayfun
Non-scalar in Uniform output, at
index 1, output 1.
Set 'UniformOutput' to false.

>> arrayfun(nums,[1,2,3],'UniformOutput',false)

ans = 

  Columns 1 through 2

    [1x3 double]    [1x3 double]

  Column 3

    [1x3 double]
```

Octave:

```
octave:1> nums=@(c) ([c, c + 2, c + 4])
nums =

@(c) ([c, c + 2, c + 4])

octave:2> arrayfun(nums,[1,2,3])
error: arrayfun: all values must be scalars when UniformOutput = true
octave:2> arrayfun(nums,[1,2,3],'UniformOutput',false)
ans = 
{
  [1,1] =

     1   3   5

  [1,2] =

     2   4   6

  [1,3] =

     3   5   7

}
octave:3>
```

If your function is really that simple, I suggest to use:

```
nums([1,2,3]')
```

Comment: Unfortunately my actual `nums` is a bit more complicated. It's more like `nums = @(c)(other_function(c, curried_argument))`.  I think that's why your last solution breaks. Yes, I could disable UniformOutput and transform the output which is maybe the most elegant thing to do, but still researching.

Comment: @djechlin then, if possible, you should consider writing the `other_function` as to accept vectors.

Comment: @carandraug I don't own it. (It's `fmincg`.)