# Matlab: How to assign values selectively to a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, matlab-guide

I have 3 matrices x, y and z of order 3*3. I want to create a new matrix k with value  = 1./(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2) if (x.^2+y.^2+z.^2 > 1)  and value = 0 otherwise.
I am trying to use this :

```
  k(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2>1)= 1./(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2)
```

but it gives error : In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same. 
Can anyone provide a simple solution in a single line where I don't need to use for loops

Comment: If (x.^2+y.^2+z.^2 > 1) for any of x's, y'x and z's or all x's, y's and z's? If the condition fails, should all 9 values in `z` must become 0?

Comment: we don't have to change z at all. we have to elementwise check the value of x.^2+y.^2+z.^2

Comment: In the condition part, you are comparing 9 values with 1. So my question was how do you want to compare? Should `all` 9 values be greater than 1 or `any` of the 9 values be greater than 1?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you'd want to do this as opposed to splitting it up into two operations. This way, you save the cost of computing the sum of squares twice.

```
x = rand(3,3);
y = rand(3,3);
z = rand(3,3);
k = 1./(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2);
k(k>1)=0;
```

---

In any case, another way to do it would be using principles of Functional Programming:

```
x = rand(3,3);
y = rand(3,3);
z = rand(3,3);
myfun = @(x,y,z) 1/(x^2+y^2+z^2) * (x^2+y^2+z^2>1);
k = arrayfun(myfun, x, y, z);
```

Alternately, you can mix everything into one line as:

```
k = arrayfun(@(x,y,z) 1/(x^2+y^2+z^2) * (x^2+y^2+z^2>1), x, y, z);
```

---

What this code does is maps the function `myfun` to each of the data elements. The function `myfun` is quite simple. It computes the required quantity but multiplies it with the binding condition. However, you might want to [beware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why).

---

EDIT: To address the comment.
If you don't want to compute the quantity at all, we can use conditional anonymous functions. For more details, you can refer to [this guide](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/01/10/introduction-to-functional-programming-with-anonymous-functions-part-1/#c8d04efb-1a2d-4c35-afff-dd52e6c660d2).

```
iif = @(varargin) varargin{2 * find([varargin{1:2:end}], 1, 'first')}();
myfun = @(x,y,z) iif( x^2+y^2+z^2 <= 1, @() 0, x^2+y^2+z^2>1 ,@() 1/(x^2+y^2+z^2));
k = arrayfun(myfun, x, y, z);
```

Comment: actually I just wanted that matlab should not compute the value of 1./(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2) for those elements where zero value is to be assigned. Can your suitably be modified to adjust this?

Comment: @Bosnia, I have edited the answer. Using the new code snippet, you will not compute the quantity if 0 is to be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
k = x.^2+y.^2+z.^2;
k(k < 1) = 0;
k(k~= 0) = 1 ./ k(k~=0);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to save some processing time (i.e. do not compute at all the sum of squares for those cases when it is less than one) then pretty much the only solution is a table lookup
Otherwise the following code should work

```
k=1./(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2)
k(k<=1)=0
```

you can cut some time (assuming x, y and z could be greater than 1)

```
idx0=x<1 & y<1 & z<1
k=zeros(3)
k(idx0)=1./(x(idx0).^2+y(idx0).^2+z(idx0)^2)
k(k<=1)=0
```

Your original solution will work if you change it to use an indexer (I haven't profiled it, but I am pretty sure it will take longer, than mine :) )

```
idx0=x.^2+y.^2+z.^2>1
k=zeros(3)
k(idx0)=1./(x(idx0).^2+y(idx0).^2+z(idx0)^2)
```

Comment: I am trying to save on computation of 1./(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2) for those elements where a zero is to be assigned. (It is actually a complicated  function of 1./(x.^2+y.^2+z.^2) so it'll take long computation time)

Comment: In your original example, than can be modified to work, the sum of squares will be computed more than once for each element (one in a conditional statement and one for those cases that fit the conditional). Mine saves at least the second time. Anyway, what is the type and the range of values for x,y,z and what is the precision of the result do you need?

Comment: type double x,y,z are from 0-5.038