# How to best construct a matrix whose elements are exactly their indices or functions of the indices in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

What is the best way to construct a matrix whose elements are exactly their indices in Matlab?

---

EDIT: The existing answers to this question is applicable to how to construct a matrix whose elements are *functions* of their indices. So I added that to the question title.

---

The format can be either a matrix with vectors as elements, or as two matrices each storing one index.

At the end, I would like to create a matrix whose elements are functions of their indices. So an efficient method for that (but possibly different) is very much appreciated. Any comment on efficiency is welcomed.

The size of matrices tends to be large (dimension of hundreds squared at the minimum) for my applications. As a result, methods that take advantage of native Matlab functions are probably much better than for/while loops.

For example, for a matrix of size [2 2], I would like to make either

```
IND = 
[1 1]  [1 2]
[2 1]  [2 2]
```

or

```
X = 
1 1
2 2
Y =
1 2
1 2
```

At the end, I am hoping to do something like

```
matrixIneed = arrayfun(@(s)..., IND)
```

where s is a vector of size 2, or

```
matrixIneed = arrayfun(@(i,j)..., X,Y)
```

The latter is preferred.

---

EDIT: A note about accepted answer.

I have accepted Andrew's answer because it is intuitive to me and the code seems quick (at least to me).

If you ever Google an answer to this question, you are likely concerned about performance like I do. (Otherwise if not for best practice, anyone can think of a double loop to accomplish the task.)

If so, you are encouraged to examine Andrew's comment on the `reshape()` function and Rody's answer about the performance of `meshgrid()` and `loops`.

Nevertheless, thewaywewalk's solution with `meshgrid()` is a helpful example to learn the `meshgrid()` function. And it is useful in many other Matlab functions.

Jigg's `repmat()` solution may help you too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the `ind2sub`, `sub2ind`, and `reshape` functions. They're useful for transforming subscripts and indexes on multidimensional arrays.

In your case, it looks like you want this. (I think you want "subscripts" instead of "indices". Matlab uses "index" to mean the "linear" index of an element when viewing the array as a one-dimensional vector, and "subscripts" to mean the position along each dimension of a multidimensional array.)

```
sz = [3 3];  % Size of your matrix
n = prod(sz); % Total number of elements in matrix
[X, Y] = ind2sub(sz, 1:n);  % Subscripts, returned as vectors
X = reshape(X, sz);  % Reshape the subscript vectors to match your matrix
Y = reshape(Y, sz);
```

The `meshgrid` approach that @thewaywewalk gave will produce the same output, but I think the `ind2sub` approach is a bit more readable in this case, since it's worded in terms of array indexing, which is your problem domain. And it will generalize to working on slices or arbitrary subsets of arrays, which `meshgrid` will not, and corresponds nicely to `ind2sub` for efficient operations going the other way. (It's worth learning `meshgrid` anyway though; it pops up in other locations.)

Comment: Hi Andrew, this is actually my first attempt too! (meshgrid was and still is confusing me..)  Do you also happen to know how reshape() performs?

Comment: Reshape is very fast. It does not change the underlying primitive data array at all; it just rewrites the dimensions in the header of the "mxArray" C structure that implements the array in the Matlab interpreter, possibly rewriting the array if it's shared by copy-on-write. That's about as fast as Matlab functions get.

Answer (score 7):

use `meshgrid` or `ndgrid`:

```
% example matrix
Matrix = magic(5)

[n m] = size(Matrix)
% or define the dimensions directly
n = 5;
m = 5;

[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:n,1:m)     %\\ [Y,X] = ndgrid(1:n,1:m)
```

(the difference for your 2D case is that, `Y` and `X` are swapped. - use it according to your needs.)

From the [**documentation**](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html):

> `[X,Y] = meshgrid(xgv,ygv)` replicates the grid vectors `xgv` and `ygv` to
>   produce a full grid. This grid is represented by the output coordinate
>   arrays `X` and `Y`. The output coordinate arrays `X` and `Y` contain
>   copies of the grid vectors `xgv` and `ygv` respectively. The sizes of the
>   output arrays are determined by the length of the grid vectors. For
>   grid vectors `xgv` and `ygv` of length `M` and `N` respectively, `X` and `Y` will
>   have `N` rows and `M` columns.

Well there is not much more to explain, `meshgrid` is used to create a regular grid from two vectors, usually "`x`" and "`y`" values in order to obtain suitable input data for a 3D/color-coded plot of `z`-data. If you assume your `x` and `y` to be the vectors `[1 2 3 ... n]` it does exactly what you need.

returns:

```
X =

     1     2     3     4     5
     1     2     3     4     5
     1     2     3     4     5
     1     2     3     4     5
     1     2     3     4     5


Y =

     1     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3     3
     4     4     4     4     4
     5     5     5     5     5
```

Comment: Hi, I am a little confused with meshgrid. Could you kindly explain why meshgrid works in this case in your answer please?

Comment: @Argyll: I added some explanations, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

Get used to [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html). Avoid [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html), except in support of plotting and graphics operations.

The output of `ndgrid`, expressed in terms of rows, columns, etc., has more natural semenatics for MATLAB matrix operations than x,y coordinates, as returned by `meshgrid`.

```
>> nrows = 3;
>> ncols = 4;
>> [II,JJ] = ndgrid(1:nrows,1:ncols)
II =
     1     1     1     1
     2     2     2     2
     3     3     3     3
JJ =
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
     1     2     3     4
```

MATLAB's dimension ordering is rows as first dimension, columns as second, then higher dimensions.  `ndgrid` follows this convention with the ordering of its inputs and outputs. For reference, the equivalent `meshgrid` command is `[JJ,II] = meshgrid(1:ncols,1:nrows);`.

An excellent illustration of why you should stick to the rows,columns frame of mind is converting to linear indexes: `sub2ind`.  The function `sub2ind` expects subscripts ordered in the same way as the outputs of `ndgrid`:

```
>> inds = sub2ind([nrows ncols],II,JJ)
inds =
     1     4     7    10
     2     5     8    11
     3     6     9    12
```

Formulating this command requires little thought if you are always thinking in terms of rows,columns (subscripts) rather than x,y.

Again, use `ndgrid`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have indicated you want to run a function on the indices, it is by far the easiest and probably fastest to  just make a double loop:

```
matrixIneed = zeros(n,m);
for ii = 1:n
    for jj = 1:m
        matrixIneed(ii,jj) = myFunction(ii,jj);
    end
end
```

Depending a bit on `myFunction`, this is likely to be faster than `arrayfun`, and certainly a lot less memory intensive than `meshgrid` when `n` or `m` are relatively large; see also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why).

If you're running MATLAB R2009 or later, and your function is a built-in or can be constructed using built-ins only, the execution time of these loops vs. `meshgrid` will be comparable, but `meshgrid` will consume much more memory (O(N²) memory as opposed to O(1) for the loop). As always, profiling is key, but the double loop is probably the best all-round solution.

Sometimes, this also helps:

```
matrixIneed = zeros(n*m,1);
for ij = 1:n*m

    %// use this when possible
    matrixIneed(ij) = myFunction(ij); 

    %// otherwise, use this
    matrixIneed(ij) = myFunction(mod(ij-1,n)+1, floor((ij-1)/n)+1);  
end
reshape(matrixIneed,n,m);
```

Comment: I have been using R2011a. And I have found loops being very slow.

For example, with a matrix of a million elements, the built-in `mean()` function is about 50 times faster then a loop, even though a loop saves memory. Likely, `rand()` about 50 times faster when directly producing an array of random numbers compared to a loop. I had a custom 1-parameter function (which is a composition of elementary arithmetic operations) that performs about 50 times faster if the input is a matrix (no `arrayfun` is needed in this case) compared to a loop.

Comment: Three 50s add up to make the difference between a simulation being precise enough or not, or a simulation being doable or not. A million was still too small to me back then. So memory does matter. And I had to instead loop over matrices to accomplish the task without crashing my computer. So your answer comes as a surprise to me. Have you not encountered similar problems with Matlab loops?

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `repmat` (since the content of these matrices is redundant):

```
X=repmat((1:size(YourMatrix, 2))', 1, size(YourMatrix, 1));
Y=repmat(1:size(YourMatrix, 1), size(YourMatrix, 2), 1);
```