# In matlab, generating a matrix by adding the elements of two orthogonal vectors

Tags: matlab, matrix, orthogonal

Say I have two vectors: `X=[x0,x1,x2];` `Y=[y0,y1];`
does there exist a single command in Matlab that I can generate a 2x3 matrix Z=f(X,Y), 
where `Z=[x0+y0, x1+y0, x2+y0; x0+y1, x1+y1, x2+y1]`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a perfect case for **[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)**[*C = bsxfun(fun,A,B) applies the element-by-element binary operation specified by the function handle fun to arrays A and B, with singleton expansion enabled. In this case, @plus is the function handle needed.*] -

```
Z = bsxfun(@plus,X,Y.')
```

As an example, look at this -

```
X=[2,3,5]
Y=[1,4]
Z = bsxfun(@plus,X,Y.')
```

which gives the output -

```
X =
     2     3     5
Y =
     1     4
Z =
     3     4     6
     6     7     9
```

Comment: +1 Just watch out that `'` will alter the result (complex conjugate) if vectors are complex

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes! In this case I must use `.`, because OP has symbols - `x0`, `y0`, so one mustn't take chances :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Z = repmat(X,numel(Y),1) + repmat(Y',1,numel(X));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `ndgrid`:

```
[xx yy] = ndgrid(Y,X);
Z = xx+yy;
```

And there's the possibility to abuse `kron` as follows (but note that internally `kron` basically uses a variation of `ndgrid`):

```
Z = log(kron(exp(X),exp(Y).'));
```

Comment: One can also use `meshgrid` I guess, isn't it? +1

Comment: @Divakar Yes... but I got into the habit of always using `ndgrid` after I saw this [good advice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22461766/2586922) by @chappjc

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to Nishant anwser would be using [kron](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/kron.html):

```
   %for example
   X=[1,2,3]; Y=[1,2]
   Z = kron(X, ones(numel(Y), 1)) +  kron(ones(1, numel(X)), Y'); 

Z =

     2     3     4
     3     4     5
```

If this would suit you, you could define a function:

```
% skron for sum kron
skron = @(X,Y) kron(X, ones(numel(Y), 1)) +  kron(ones(1, numel(X)), Y');

Z = skron(X,Y);
```