# How to vectorize this operation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

The code:

```
A = NxMxLxD matrix
B = NxMxL matrix
index = NxMxL matrix containing values between 1 and D

for i=1:N
 for j=1:M
  for k=1:L
   B(i,j,k) = A(i,j,k,index(i,j,k));
  end
 end
end
```

How do I write this in vector form, that is using some built it function? I'm basically selecting with the index each point.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done as follows:

```
ind = bsxfun(@plus, bsxfun(@plus, ...
      (1:N).', N*(0:M-1)), N*M*permute(0:L-1, [3 1 2])) + N*M*L*(index-1);
B = A(ind);
```

The trick is to build a [linear index](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) (`ind` variable) that corresponds to the indexing `(i,j,k,index(i,j,k))`, vectorized. I do it with two calls to [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). The key is to remember that linear indices run along columns first, then along rows, then along third-dim slices.

The standard way would be using `ndgrid` and then `sub2ind` (see [@rayryeng`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26474665/2586922)), but that requires a little more memory.

Comment: +1 - For using `bsxfun`.  This will probably be much faster than using `meshgrid` and `sub2ind`!  It also looks like I implemented your alternative approach :).

Comment: Luis, I see you are calculating the linear indices, but you don't actually use them in the final result.  I don't even think you need a `reshape`.  You can just do `B = A(ind);`, as you have already computed the linear indices!

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks! I always get confused as to when linear indexing preserves shape and when it doesn't

Comment: Not a problem :)  I get confused too... just takes practice right!?

Comment: Now that I think about it: it _always_ preserves shape, doesn't it? I mean, `size(A(ind))` always equals `size(ind)`.

Comment: When you're computing `sub2ind`, whatever size matrices you present to it will give you the same shape yes.  Because you were using `bsxfun`, I actually couldn't tell what the shape was at first until I ran the code on my computer.

Comment: I didn't mean `sub2ind`,  but right after that, when you use `sub2ind`'s output to index into `A`: that is, the shape of `A(ind)` is the shape of `ind`.

Comment: Oh, in that case yes always!

Comment: I have just remembered what I think was confusing me about this: `A(ind)` has the same shape as `ind` when `ind` is _integer_; but when `ind` is _logical_ the shape is not kept (it can't be)

Comment: Yes that's exactly it. It will become a single vector that is as long as how many elements are True in the logical array!

Comment: @rayryeng I knew there was some caveat! (I just couldn't remember what it was). Shape is actually [not always preserved](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/08/09/essence-of-indexing/): "Indexing with one array C = A(B) produces output the size of B unless both A and B are vectors. _When both A and B are vectors, the number of elements in C is the number of elements in B and with orientation of A_.". Example: try `B = (1:3).'; A = 1:2;`. Then `B(A)` is a column, when it "should" be a row

Answer (score 1):

OK, what this looks like for your output array of `B` is that for each location in this output, the corresponding location in `A` has a `D`-element vector and you want to choose which element to select from this `D`-element vector based on the value stored in `index`, which is of the same size as `B`.

We can achieve this using a combination of [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) and [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html).  First use `meshgrid` to generate a grid of 3D co-ordinates, which will be the same size as your matrix `B`.  After, use `sub2ind` to determine a set of linear indices to access the fourth dimension of `A`.  After this, we simply do a straight assignment using the output of `sub2ind`, which uses a combination of the output of `meshgrid` and `index`.

Therefore, try something like this:

```
[cols,rows,dim] = meshgrid(1:size(A,2), 1:size(A,1), 1:size(A,3));
ind = sub2ind(size(A), rows, cols, dim, index);
B = A(ind);
```

Comment: +1 for readable code. My two `bsxfun`'s are kind of a mess :-)

Comment: It would be even more readable with `ndgrid`. Remember [@chappjc's advice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22461766/2586922)!

Comment: @LuisMendo - Good idea :)  I actually didn't know that about `ndgrid`.  I found it annoying with `meshgrid` to have to specify the second dimension range first.  With `ndgrid` I don't have to do this anymore.  Nice find Luis!

Comment: Once you go `ndgrid`, you never go back to `meshgrid` :-D