# Meshgrid and double for-loops does not result in the same matrix, why?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to evaluate all values the expression f = 2y-exp(z) can take for different values of z and y. Were y and z are two vectors of length M. I am wondering why the two approaches for generating the expression f yields different results.

Using meshgrid:

```
    [Y,Z] = meshgrid(y,z);
argument = 2*Y-exp(Z);
```

and with double for-loops

```
argument_new = zeros(M,M);
for i = 1:length(y)
    for j = 1:length(z)
    argument_new(i,j) = 2*y(i)-exp(z(j));
    end
end
```

Any hints will be highly appreciated!

Comment: [What Luis Mendo said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27495521/2778484).  But here's [my 2 cents](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22461766/2778484).

Comment: so @user3748876 does any of the answer below helped you? If so please mark them as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because of the way `meshgrid` creates 'inverted' directions. I don't find the right words, but here is an example illustrating with your code.You see that if you uncomment option 2 and use `argument_new(j,i)` instead of `argument_new(i,j)` both matrices are equal (as obtained with `isequal`).

```
clear
clc

M = 20;
y = 1:M;
z = 1:M;

[Y,Z] = meshgrid(y,z);
argument = 2*Y-exp(Z);

argument_new = zeros(M,M);
for i = 1:length(y)
    for j = 1:length(z)
    %// 1)    
    argument_new(i,j) = 2*y(i)-exp(z(j));
    %// 2)
    %// argument_new(j,i) = 2*y(i)-exp(z(j));
    end
end

isequal(argument,argument_new) %// Gives 0 for option 1 and 1 for option 2.
```

Answer (score 2):

Blame that on [`meshgrid`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html):

> MESHGRID is like NDGRID except that **the order of the first two input
>       and output arguments are switched** (i.e., [X,Y,Z] = MESHGRID(x,y,z)
>       produces the same result as [Y,X,Z] = NDGRID(y,x,z)).

Solution: use [`ndgrid`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html),  which doesn't do that switching, and is thus more "natural":

```
[Y,Z] = ndgrid(y,z);
argument = 2*Y-exp(Z);
```

Or in your code, after `meshgrid`, add a transpose operation: `argument = argument.';)`

Comment: I think @chappjc would have liked to answer this :-)

Comment: Bah! Haha, alas, I was chugging through a pointless review queue!

Comment: Yup... `meshgrid` has truly messed me up quite a few times. +1.

Comment: @chappjc Hmmm... looking for hats, are you?

Comment: Looking and found.  I now have a soccer ball on my head... or should I say fútbol.  ;)

Comment: @chappjc Deffinitely nicer than the android you had :-P (and the hat tilting feature is a nice addition this year). I'm a great fan of fútbol by the way!

Comment: @LuisMendo - ... but I like Android!  I changed my hat to that!  BTW, this post is interesting: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245170/winter-bash-2014-secret-hats

Comment: @LuisMendo - Never mind... Joga Bonito! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IjMHJCKGBzg

Comment: @rayryeng I do like Android a lot... but not so much the hat :-) Nice ad, I didn't know it!

Answer (score 0):

They are the same, you should just transpose either one (' in Matlab), or you can replace i by j and vice versa in the for loops