# MATLAB: Indexing arrays with arrays of integers

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix-indexing

`MATLAB` allows to index arrays with other arrays.

Usually the result has the same size, but apparently this is not always the case.

It must have to do with "*column priority*" in `MATLAB`.

QUESTION:

I am wondering how to find a consistent solution on how to get `[1 1]` in

`size(index_array)==size(array(index_array))` for *ALL* sizes of `index_array`.

To be specific I post a sample script:

```
baseAlt = [ 0, 11000, 20000, 32000, 47000, 51000, 71000 ];

xRow = 10000*[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
xCol = 10000*[ 1; 2; 3; 4; 5];
 xSq = 20000* rand(5);

reg = arrayfun( @(alt) sum(alt>=baseAlt), xRow);
ans1 = baseAlt(reg);
disp(all(size(baseAlt(reg))==size(reg))); %ans=2

reg = arrayfun( @(alt) sum(alt>=baseAlt), xSq);
ans2 = baseAlt(reg);
disp(all(size(baseAlt(reg))==size(reg))); % ans=2

%BUUUUT
reg = arrayfun( @(alt) sum(alt>=baseAlt), xCol);
ans3 = baseAlt(reg);
disp(all(size(baseAlt(reg))==size(reg)));       % row, instead of column
                                                % zero when comparing size
%MOREOVER
reg = arrayfun( @(alt) sum(alt>=baseAlt), xCol);
ans4 = baseAlt([reg,reg]);
disp(all(size(baseAlt([reg,reg]))==size([reg,reg])));  % we get true here
```

As you can see, all the matrices retain the shape of the indexing matrices, *APART* from the case when a *ROW gets indexed by a COL*. Could anyone shed light on this please?

EDIT 1: Used "all" instead of "sum", which, as Dani pointed out, is much more elengant here.

Answer (score 0):

I was not aware indexing worked in the way you showed (the Matrix indexing a vector especially). Neither did I find this in the Matlab documentation on a first look.

The reason why your 3rd example does not work is because Matlab interprets the index vector as a linear index (whether it is a row- or column vector is inconsequential).

You can easily implement your desired behavior by using this small anonymous function:

```
arrayIndexing = @(ar, ind)arrayfun(@(x)ar(x),ind);
```

With your example code (for quick testing):

```
baseAlt = [ 0, 11000, 20000, 32000, 47000, 51000, 71000 ];
xRow = 10000*[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
xCol = 10000*[ 1; 2; 3; 4; 5];
xSq = 20000* rand(5);
arrayIndexing = @(ar, ind)arrayfun(@(x)ar(x),ind);
reg = arrayfun( @(alt) sum(alt>=baseAlt), xSq);
result = arrayIndexing(baseAlt,reg);
disp(all(size(result)==size(reg))); % ans=1
reg = arrayfun( @(alt) sum(alt>=baseAlt), xCol);
result = arrayIndexing(baseAlt,reg);
disp(all(size(result)==size(reg)));  % ans=1
```

This will work for any format of the indexing vector/array.

Note the usage of `all` instead of `sum`, I think it is the more fitting function here.

Comment: I am aware of arrayfun, it is, as any "type-independent" function, slow. The topic of whether to use "for", or "arrayfun" or vectorisation is BEAUTIFULLY discussed here:

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why

That is why I wanted to avoid using "arrafuns", mostly nested in other "arrayfuns", which is the case when you have more matrices to work on.

To sum up--I'd like to use MATLAB's flexible indexing framework.

Comment: And ofc "all" is the much more fitting function!

Comment: Okay, if speed is of the essence, arrayfuns are not the way to go, thats true. But I don't think you will get around the whole 'index vector'=>'linear index' issue. All I can think of is writing a function that basically does the indexing as you described, then checks if the index is a column vector and if so transposes the output. Not pretty but I think that's the most straight-forward way - AFAIK.

Comment: That is the way I do it now, as the ONLY case in which my fast approach goes wrong is when a row meets a col. So I do an if with a size check that would eventually transpose 'baseAlt'. As a purist, I do not like it... hence my Q.

Comment: REMARK: But maybe others will prove, that using 'isrow/isvector' is in fact the cleanest way out of linear indexing, rearranging etc. business.