# Computing the correlation coefficient between two multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, correlation

I have two arrays that have the shapes `N X T` and `M X T`.  I'd like to compute the correlation coefficient across `T` between every possible pair of rows `n` and `m` (from `N` and `M`, respectively).

What's the fastest, most pythonic way to do this?  (Looping over `N` and `M` would seem to me to be neither fast nor pythonic.)  I'm expecting the answer to involve `numpy` and/or `scipy`.  Right now my arrays are `numpy` `array`s, but I'm open to converting them to a different type.

I'm expecting my output to be an array with the shape `N X M`.

N.B. When I say "correlation coefficient," I mean the [Pearson product-moment correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_product-moment_correlation_coefficient).

Here are some things to note:

- The `numpy` function `correlate` requires input arrays to be one-dimensional.
- The `numpy` function `corrcoef` accepts two-dimensional arrays, but they must have the same shape.
- The `scipy.stats` function `pearsonr` requires input arrays to be one-dimensional.

Comment: So are you looking for `"same"`, `''full"` or the default one with `np.correlate`? Did you write the loopy version of the solution?

Comment: i'm looking for `'valid'`.

Comment: yeah, the loopy version is trivial: `for n in range(N):` . . . `for m in range(M):` . . . `correlate(arr_one[n, :], arr_two[m, :])` . . .

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**Correlation (default 'valid' case) between two 2D arrays:**

You can simply use matrix-multiplication [`np.dot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) like so -

```
out = np.dot(arr_one,arr_two.T)
```

Correlation with the default `"valid"` case between each pairwise row combinations (row1,row2) of the two input arrays would correspond to multiplication result at each (row1,row2) position.

---

**Row-wise Correlation Coefficient calculation for two 2D arrays:**

```
def corr2_coeff(A, B):
    # Rowwise mean of input arrays & subtract from input arrays themeselves
    A_mA = A - A.mean(1)[:, None]
    B_mB = B - B.mean(1)[:, None]

    # Sum of squares across rows
    ssA = (A_mA**2).sum(1)
    ssB = (B_mB**2).sum(1)

    # Finally get corr coeff
    return np.dot(A_mA, B_mB.T) / np.sqrt(np.dot(ssA[:, None],ssB[None]))
```

This is based upon this solution to [`How to apply corr2 functions in Multidimentional arrays in MATLAB`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26526798/3293881)

**Benchmarking**

This section compares runtime performance with the proposed approach against `generate_correlation_map` & loopy `pearsonr` based approach listed in the [other answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30145770/3293881)(taken from the function `test_generate_correlation_map()` without the value correctness verification code at the end of it). Please note the timings for the proposed approach also include a check at the start to check for equal number of columns in the two input arrays, as also done in that other answer. The runtimes are listed next.

Case #1:

```
In [106]: A = np.random.rand(1000, 100)

In [107]: B = np.random.rand(1000, 100)

In [108]: %timeit corr2_coeff(A, B)
100 loops, best of 3: 15 ms per loop

In [109]: %timeit generate_correlation_map(A, B)
100 loops, best of 3: 19.6 ms per loop
```

Case #2:

```
In [110]: A = np.random.rand(5000, 100)

In [111]: B = np.random.rand(5000, 100)

In [112]: %timeit corr2_coeff(A, B)
1 loops, best of 3: 368 ms per loop

In [113]: %timeit generate_correlation_map(A, B)
1 loops, best of 3: 493 ms per loop
```

Case #3:

```
In [114]: A = np.random.rand(10000, 10)

In [115]: B = np.random.rand(10000, 10)

In [116]: %timeit corr2_coeff(A, B)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.29 s per loop

In [117]: %timeit generate_correlation_map(A, B)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.83 s per loop
```

The other loopy `pearsonr based` approach seemed too slow, but here are the runtimes for one small datasize -

```
In [118]: A = np.random.rand(1000, 100)

In [119]: B = np.random.rand(1000, 100)

In [120]: %timeit corr2_coeff(A, B)
100 loops, best of 3: 15.3 ms per loop

In [121]: %timeit generate_correlation_map(A, B)
100 loops, best of 3: 19.7 ms per loop

In [122]: %timeit pearsonr_based(A, B)
1 loops, best of 3: 33 s per loop
```

Comment: nice.  i did not realize `newaxis` was an alias for `None`.  i think you're missing a `, :` from the slice into `sb1` on the second-to-last line. it'd be interesting to time our answers as compared to the double-for-loop method.

Comment: @dbliss That [None] was intentional, to make that a row vector and the other one was made a column vector with [:,None]. All that was required to make broadcasting come into play. Added runtime tests, check those out.

Comment: nice effort, but i'm not sure how informative the timing results you report are.  for example, `test_generate_correlation_map` includes both the loop method and my function `generate_correlation_map`.  and, though this probably wouldn't make much of a difference, `generate_correlation_map` checks that the two inputs have the same size second dimension, whereas yours does not.  that said, i think it's safe to conclude your function is faster than mine.  but it may be true that a hybrid function is the best -- line-by-line timing information would speak to that.

Comment: @dbliss Do you mind if I include the error checking portion of your code and update the code proposed in this solution and runtimes? I didn't bother to include as the question said at the start that those two arrays have the same number of columns as T.

Comment: @dbliss Updated the runtimes for the proposed approach that includes the same error-checking that you used in your approach. The error checking didn't change the runtimes from the previous runs by a big margin, which was expected. Also, I am not sure what you would be looking for in line-by-line timing information. Is there something specific in mind you have with it?

Comment: it looks like you've updated `test_generate_correlation_map`'s time, and it's increased.  i'm not sure what happened there.  perhaps you had already cut out the call to `generate_correlation_map` in your first post?  re: the line-by-line timing: you calculate your numerator and your denominator differently from how i do.  it could be that your numerator calculation is faster than mine, but your denominator calculation is slower, or the other way around.

Comment: @dbliss I had updated all the runtimes, so all these runtimes are for a fresh run and with my code having the error-checking included (not shown in the solution though). So, if you see the revision history, everything of those runtimes must have changed a bit because of these being run at a different time. Regarding the numerator calculation, I would say mine must be faster as my method is basically a raw version of covariance calculation. The denominator looks the same as yours, so I am not hoping to see much of timing difference for the denominator part.

Comment: @dbliss Hope this answers all your doubts. Just curious - Any particular reason for the downvote?

Comment: hmm, i'm still confused about the timing for `test_generate_correlation_map`: did you test the function as written in my answer?  if so, this timing information is not very informative, for the reason i mentioned.  if not, this is not clear.  sure, thanks for the question re: the downvote.  it merely reflects my confusion about the timing information you report.  i'm looking forward to changing it back to an upvote! :)

Comment: @dbliss The `test_generate_correlation_map` function I have used stops after getting out of the two nested loops, so it doesn't include any call to `generate_correlation_map`. I do understand that you had used `actual = generate_correlation_map(x, y)` and then `np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(actual, desired)` just to verify for value correctness, so be sure that those are not part of the runtime tests for `test_generate_correlation_map`. Does this answer your question(s)?

Comment: exactly, yes, well done!  you do not state in your answer that you have edited the code of `test_generate_correlation_map`.  hence my confusion about whether you had performed the runtime tests correctly.

Comment: @dbliss Updated the solution to cover all those clarifications.

Comment: why not simply use Scipy's [correlated_2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate2d.html)?

Answer (score 13):

@Divakar provides a great option for computing the unscaled correlation, which is what I originally asked for.

In order to calculate the correlation coefficient, a bit more is required:

```
import numpy as np

def generate_correlation_map(x, y):
    """Correlate each n with each m.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : np.array
      Shape N X T.

    y : np.array
      Shape M X T.

    Returns
    -------
    np.array
      N X M array in which each element is a correlation coefficient.

    """
    mu_x = x.mean(1)
    mu_y = y.mean(1)
    n = x.shape[1]
    if n != y.shape[1]:
        raise ValueError('x and y must ' +
                         'have the same number of timepoints.')
    s_x = x.std(1, ddof=n - 1)
    s_y = y.std(1, ddof=n - 1)
    cov = np.dot(x,
                 y.T) - n * np.dot(mu_x[:, np.newaxis],
                                  mu_y[np.newaxis, :])
    return cov / np.dot(s_x[:, np.newaxis], s_y[np.newaxis, :])
```

Here's a test of this function, which passes:

```
from scipy.stats import pearsonr

def test_generate_correlation_map():
    x = np.random.rand(10, 10)
    y = np.random.rand(20, 10)
    desired = np.empty((10, 20))
    for n in range(x.shape[0]):
        for m in range(y.shape[0]):
            desired[n, m] = pearsonr(x[n, :], y[m, :])[0]
    actual = generate_correlation_map(x, y)
    np.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(actual, desired)
```

Answer (score 2):

For those interested in computing the Pearson correlation coefficient between a 1D and 2D array, I wrote the following function, where `x` is a 1D array and `y` a 2D array.

```
def pearsonr_2D(x, y):
    """computes pearson correlation coefficient
       where x is a 1D and y a 2D array"""

    upper = np.sum((x - np.mean(x)) * (y - np.mean(y, axis=1)[:,None]), axis=1)
    lower = np.sqrt(np.sum(np.power(x - np.mean(x), 2)) * np.sum(np.power(y - np.mean(y, axis=1)[:,None], 2), axis=1))
    
    rho = upper / lower
    
    return rho
```

Example run:

```
>>> x
Out[1]: array([1, 2, 3])

>>> y
Out[2]: array([[ 1,  2,  3],
               [ 6,  7, 12],
               [ 9,  3,  1]])

>>> pearsonr_2D(x, y)
Out[3]: array([ 1.        ,  0.93325653, -0.96076892])
```

Comment: This is useful for comparing one sample to large database. I'm using it for user-based collaborative filtering. Thanks.

Comment: What about p_value?