# How to perform Correlation between two dataframes with different column names

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of columns (col1,col2,col3) in dataframe df1
I have another set of columns (col4,col5,col6) in dataframe df2
Assume this two dataframes has the same number of rows.

How do I generate a correlation table that do pairwise correlation between df1 and df2?

the table will look like

```
    col1 col2 col3
col4 ..   ..   ..
col5 ..   ..   ..
col6 ..   ..   ..
```

I use `df1.corrwith(df2)`, it does not seem to generate the table as required.

I have seen the answer at [How to check correlation between matching columns of two data sets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41004952/how-to-check-correlation-between-matching-columns-of-two-data-sets), but the main difference is that the col names does not matched.

Answer (score 25):

***`pandas` quick and dirty***

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=['df1', 'df2']).corr().loc['df2', 'df1']
```

***`numpy` clean***

```
def corr(df1, df2):
    n = len(df1)
    v1, v2 = df1.values, df2.values
    sums = np.multiply.outer(v2.sum(0), v1.sum(0))
    stds = np.multiply.outer(v2.std(0), v1.std(0))
    return pd.DataFrame((v2.T.dot(v1) - sums / n) / stds / n,
                        df2.columns, df1.columns)

corr(df1, df2)
```

---

***example***

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=list('abcd'))

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 3), columns=list('xyz'))
```

---

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=['df1', 'df2']).corr().loc['df2', 'df1']

          a         b         c         d
x  0.235624  0.844665 -0.647962  0.535562
y  0.357994  0.462007  0.205863  0.424568
z  0.688853  0.350318  0.132357  0.687038
```

---

```
corr(df1, df2)

          a         b         c         d
x  0.235624  0.844665 -0.647962  0.535562
y  0.357994  0.462007  0.205863  0.424568
z  0.688853  0.350318  0.132357  0.687038
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am comparing categorical fields instead, I decided to ask it as a new question, could you help take a look here, thanks in advance:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41827716/how-to-perform-correlation-between-categorical-columns

Comment: @piRSquared Why do you say that the pandas solution is 'dirty'? I think it is a great one-liner that should be part of pandas package

Comment: @tashuhka you’re right. More quick and less dirty (-:

Comment: I tried to use this but I get KeyError: ('df1', 'df2')

Comment: I tried to use this but I get different correlation values from the actual/manual calculation in excel.

Comment: I tried to use this but I get different correlation values from the actual/manual calculation in excel. I inserted  ```df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)'''