# How to perform correlation between categorical columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a set of columns (col1,col2,col3) in dataframe df1
I have another set of columns (col4,col5,col6) in dataframe df2
Assume this two dataframes has the same number of rows.

How do I generate a correlation table that do pairwise correlation between df1 and df2?

the table will look like

```
    col1 col2 col3
col4 ..   ..   ..
col5 ..   ..   ..
col6 ..   ..   ..
```

I use `df1.corrwith(df2)`, it does not seem to generate the table as required.

I have a asked a similar question here:
[How to perform Correlation between two dataframes with different column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823728/how-to-perform-correlation-between-two-dataframes-with-different-column-names)
but now I am dealing with categorical columns.

If it is not comparable directly, is there a standard way to make it comparable (like using get_dummies)? and is that a faster way to automatically process all fields (assume all are categorical) and calculate their correlation?

Comment: get_dummies would make the variables binary. in turn you would be able to apply the correlation function to them.

Comment: Pearson correlation requires data to be numeric. The correlation you calculate on binary data has no meaning. Look for the association measures on categorical data.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct that `pd.get_dummies` would be needed to get the correlation. Below, I will create some fake data with two categorical columns and then use `corrwith`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.random.choice(list('abcde'),100),
                  'col2':np.random.choice(list('xyz'),100)}, dtype='category')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.random.choice(list('abcde'),100),
                   'col2':np.random.choice(list('xyz'),100)}, dtype='category')

dfa = pd.get_dummies(df)
dfb = pd.get_dummies(df1)
dfa.corrwith(dfb)

col1_a   -0.057735
col1_b    0.002513
col1_c    0.137956
col1_d   -0.095050
col1_e   -0.114022
col2_x    0.022568
col2_y   -0.081699
col2_z   -0.128350
```

Comment: can we also check the significance of the correlation test statistic using this approach?