# How to find co-relation between two different tables and generate heat map?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

There are two tables with some values.

Table 1

```
   A  B  C
1           
2           
3
```

Table 2

```
   D  E  F
1           
2           
3
```

*where 1,2,3 are rows*

I want to find co relation between these two tables in python

Resultant Correlation Table

```
   D  E  F
A           
B           
C
```

Comment: can give an example to your data, what's the meaning of correlation between `A` to `F` with respect to the column data?

Answer (score 0):

**Generating a correlation matrix between two sets of columns**

You could use the pandas DataFrame.corrwith method.

For example:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],columns=['A','B','C'])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],columns=['D','E','F'])
corr_matrix = df_1.corrwith(other=df_2, axis=1) # You're using columns hence axis=1
```

EDIT:
I'm sorry I misread the documentation, which is why the solution isn't working for you. I looked into it a bit more and this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823728/how-to-perform-correlation-between-two-dataframes-with-different-column-names) will work (despite being slightly costly). In fact, this post is a duplicate.

Applied to the above problem though, you get:

```
pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1, keys=['df_1', 'df_2']).corr().loc['df_2', df_1']
```

Note that you're creating a multi-level dataframe, and then performing correlations between all the columns of df_1 with itself and the columns of df_2, and the df_2 with itself and all the columns of df_1, and then subsetting only the columns of df_2 with df_1 (which is what you wanted originally). This is costly and probably won't scale very well, but if you have two small DataFrames this should work.

**Generating a heatmap from a correlation matrix**

There are millions of medium posts with simple snippets how to do this. One of the easier ways would be to use seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(corr_matrix)
```

If you need a more specific example try [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/better-heatmaps-and-correlation-matrix-plots-in-python-41445d0f2bec)

Comment: 0
0 nan
1 nan
2 nan  is the output