# Correlation coefficient between a 2D and a 3D array - NumPy/Python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, vectorization

Let

```
import numpy as np
A = np.ones([n,m])
B = np.ones([o,n,m])
```

Is there any way to compute correlation coefficient witout looping such that

```
C = corr(A,B) = array([1,o])
```

Where `m`, `n` and `o` are used to express dimension.

Loopy Example:

```
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr

A = np.random.random([5,5])
B = np.random.random([3,5,5])
C = []
for i in B:
    C.append(pearsonr(A.flatten(), i.flatten())[0])

C = np.array(C)
```

Comment: This might be relevant : [`Computing the correlation coefficient between two multi-dimensional arrays`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30143417/3293881).

Comment: Could you add a working loopy implementation that we could try to vectorize?

Comment: Example added @Divakar

Comment: Did the posted solution work for you?

Comment: you will be informed @Divakar

Comment: for

    A = np.random.rand(300,300)
    B = np.random.rand(5000,300, 300)

jut not working. @Divakar

Comment: Elaborate on "not working"?

Comment: after 5 minutes or so I had to shut down my computer, it took 100% of memory. @Divakar

Comment: For such huge dataset, you need to focus on memory optimization. So, use one loop like so - `[corr2_coeff(A.reshape(1,-1), i.reshape(1,-1)) for i in B]`. This should still be much better than your loopy version. Let me know if this works for you, I will add that to my post and be done with this question.

Comment: yap!!! its some what better (almost same) than previous thnx. @Divakar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `corr2_coeff` from [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30143754/3293881) after reshaping the inputs to `2D` versions, such that the first input is reshaped to a one-column array and the second one would have number of columns same as the combined length of its last two axes, like so -

```
corr2_coeff(A.reshape(1,-1),B.reshape(B.shape[0],-1)).ravel()
```

Sample run -

```
In [143]: from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr
     ...: 
     ...: A = np.random.random([5,5])
     ...: B = np.random.random([3,5,5])
     ...: C = []
     ...: for i in B:
     ...:     C.append(pearsonr(A.flatten(), i.flatten())[0])
     ...: 
     ...: C = np.array(C)
     ...: 

In [144]: C
Out[144]: array([ 0.05637413, -0.26749579, -0.08957621])

In [145]: corr2_coeff(A.reshape(1,-1),B.reshape(B.shape[0],-1)).ravel()
Out[145]: array([ 0.05637413, -0.26749579, -0.08957621])
```

For really huge arrays, we might need to resort to one-loop, like so -

```
[corr2_coeff(A.reshape(1,-1), i.reshape(1,-1)) for i in B]
```