# Python3 - Computationally efficient correlation between matrix and array

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, numpy, correlation

I'd like to correlate the columns of an mxn matrix with a 1xm array. This should give me an 1xn array back. At the moment I am doing this a bit clumsy with:

`c = np.corrcoef(X, y)[:-1,-1]`

I find the correlations I want here in the last column and with the last row/column corresponding to the correlation the array have with it self (so r = 1.0).

This is fine, but however, I need to do this on quite big matrices and that is  basically when it becomes too computationally heavy and my computer gives up.

**For example the largest matrix I am doing this for has the size**:

48x290400 (= X) and 48x1 (=y), where I want to end up with 290400 r-values

This works fine in Matlab, but not in python using np.corrcoef. Anyone got a good solution for this?

Cheers
Daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `corr2_coeff` from [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30143754/3293881) after transposing the input arrays -

```
corr2_coeff(a.T,b.T).ravel()
```

Sample run -

```
In [160]: a = np.random.rand(3, 5)

In [161]: b = np.random.rand(3, 1)

# Proposed in the question
In [162]: np.corrcoef(a.T, b.T)[:-1,-1]
Out[162]: array([-0.0716,  0.1905,  0.9699,  0.7482, -0.1511])

# Proposed in this post
In [163]: corr2_coeff(a.T,b.T).ravel()
Out[163]: array([-0.0716,  0.1905,  0.9699,  0.7482, -0.1511])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [171]: a = np.random.rand(48, 10000)

In [172]: b = np.random.rand(48, 1)

In [173]: %timeit np.corrcoef(a.T, b.T)[:-1,-1]
1 loops, best of 3: 619 ms per loop

In [174]: %timeit corr2_coeff(a.T,b.T).ravel()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.72 ms per loop

In [176]: 619.0/1.72
Out[176]: 359.8837209302326
```

Massive **`360x`** speedup there!

Scaling it further -

```
In [239]: a = np.random.rand(48, 29040)

In [240]: b = np.random.rand(48, 1)

In [241]: %timeit np.corrcoef(a.T, b.T)[:-1,-1]
1 loops, best of 3: 5.19 s per loop

In [242]: %timeit corr2_coeff(a.T,b.T).ravel()
100 loops, best of 3: 8.09 ms per loop

In [244]: 5190.0/8.09
Out[244]: 641.5327564894932
```

**`640x+`** speedup on this bigger dataset and should scale better as we go towards actual dataset sizes!

Comment: Thanks for the simulations as well! Yeah, I basically went from not being able to run at all to having my correlations within no time. Very useful