# numpy corrcoef causes computer to hang

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, windows-10, anaconda

When trying to calculate numpy corrcoef

```
cc = np.corrcoef(y, y2)
```

where shapes of `y` and `y2` are

```
<class 'tuple'>: (32383, 1)
```

My computer hangs. Not only interpreter but entire computer.

How can this be and how to fix?

Comment: What are your computer specs?

Comment: Probably you get the dimension wrong and it's returning 32k x 32k matrix, instead of a scalar

Comment: Have you taken a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143417/computing-the-correlation-coefficient-between-two-multi-dimensional-arrays) question?

Comment: @GrayCygnus 64 bit, 32 Gb RAM, GTX 1070; I don't understand why it is hang totally

Comment: @jf328 should it hang it the case or complain OOM?

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html), by default "each row represents a variable, with observations in the columns". Having shape `(32383, 1)` means 32383 variables with 1 observation for each, which is totally meaningless for correlation purposes. So, the computer behavior aside, the way to proceed is

```
cc = np.corrcoef(y, y2, rowvar=False)
```

indicating that your *columns* correspond to variables.

Answer (score 0):

Computing the correlation coefficient between two shape `(32383, 1)` arrays will result in a `(32383, 32383)` array. Such an array will have size `(32383 * 32383 * 8) / (1024 ** 3) = 7.8 Gb`. Considering that you likely have some overhead in computing the result, you likely need in the order of tens of Gb's to compute this.

What is probably happening is not that your computer hangs, but that the computation overflows your RAM and starts to perform [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging), that is, uses the hard-drive to store the partial results. This is exceedingly slow and it will thus seem like your computer has hung. Given enough time, it should give a result.

If you instead want to compute the row-wise cross correlation (which has shape `(1, 1)`), you can do:

```
cc = np.corrcoef(y, y2, rowvar=False)
```

Comment: When computer overloads paging it doesn't turn to complete brick. In this case even mouse stops moving. How can it be?