# Computing row-wise correlation coefficients between two 2d arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, correlation

I have two numpy arrays of identical size `M X T` (let's call them `A` and `B`). I'd like to compute the Pearson correlation coefficient across T between each pair of *the same row* m in A and B (so, `A[i,:]` and `B[i,:]`, then `A[j,:]` and `B[j,:]`; but never `A[i,:]` and `B[j,:]`, for example).

I'm expecting my output to be either a one-dimensional array with shape `(M,)` or a two-dimensional array with shape `(M,1)`.

The arrays are quite large (on the order of 1-2 million rows), so I'm looking for a vectorized solution that will let me avoid a for-loop.  Apologies if this has already been answered, but it seems like many of the code snippets in previous answers (e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143417/computing-the-correlation-coefficient-between-two-multi-dimensional-arrays)) are designed to give the full `M X M` correlation matrix -- i.e., correlation coefficients between all possible pairs of rows, rather than just index-matched rows; what I am looking for is basically just the diagonal of this matrix, but it feels wasteful to calculate the whole thing if all I need is the diagonal -- and in fact it's throwing memory errors when I try to do that anyway....

What's the fastest way to implement this? Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd just use a list-comprehension and a module for calculating the coefficient:

```
from scipy.stats.stats import pearsonr
import numpy as np

M = 10
T = 4
A = np.random.rand(M*T).reshape((M, T))
B = np.random.rand(M*T).reshape((M, T))
diag_pear_coef = [pearsonr(A[i, :], B[i, :])[0] for i in range(M)]
```

Does that work for you? Note that `pearsonr` returns more than just the correlation coefficient, hence the `[0]` indexing.
Good luck!

Comment: Yes, thank you! I figured it was something simple like this but I'm new to Python and still wrapping my head around list comprehension. Thanks again.

Comment: Interesting that there is no implemented function for this in numpy or scipy?