# Compute correlation of two DataFrames columnwise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, correlation

I have two `DataFrame`s and I want to compute their correlations without looping:

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(0,4), 'B': range(14,10,-1)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'C': range(104,100,-1), 'D': range(2,6), 'E': range(11,7,-1)})
corr = pd.DataFrame(dict(c1=c1, **{c2:df2[c2].corr(df1[c1]) for c2 in df2.columns})
                    for c1 in df1.columns).set_index("c1")
corr.index.name = None
```

Now `corr` is

```py
     C    D    E
A -1.0  1.0 -1.0
B  1.0 -1.0  1.0
```

Neither [`DataFrame.corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html) nor [`DataFrame.corrwith`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corrwith.html) do what I need.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143417/computing-the-correlation-coefficient-between-two-multi-dimensional-arrays

Comment: Wow, that link was news to me. I wonder why `pandas` favors the double loop in DataFrame.corr()? It it because it's a bit more free to deal with different methods, or is is just a memory concern once you're in the world of 50 columns and 40M+ rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the methods `apply` and `corrwith`:

```
df2.apply(df1.corrwith)
```

Output:

```
     C    D    E
A -1.0  1.0 -1.0
B  1.0 -1.0  1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatem:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=['df1', 'df2']).corr().loc['df1', 'df2']

     C    D    E
A -1.0  1.0 -1.0
B  1.0 -1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Prettier than the other answer, thanks, but still imperfect in that it computes (n+m)^2 correlations instead of n*m correlations.

Comment: (the other answer I refer to has now been deleted)