# Vectorizing a multi-satement for loop

Tags: matlab, vectorization

Is there a way to vectorize code of the same form as what I have below?

```
for k=1:length(channel_cuttoffs)
    [b a] = butter(5,channel_cuttoffs(k));
    pulse = filtfilt(b,a,pulse);
    eyediagram(downsample(pulse,10),3)
end
```

`pulse` is 10000x1 and `channel_cuttoffs` is 1x5.

Comment: I don't think the `butter` function allows vectors as input, so I guess it is not really possible. You could go through `channel_cuttoffs` with `arrayfun` but I'm not sure this improves performance.

Comment: There's no reason to.  These functions are all fairly heavyweight (especially the graphics output), so the time percentage spent on "loop overhead" is very small.  Keep it readable.

Comment: I will keep it as is, in that case.

Answer (score 2):

You could use arrayfun to vectorise the code.

Something like:

```
[b a] = arrayfun(@(x), butter(5, x), channelcuttoffs);
pulse = arrayfun(@(x, y), filtfilt(x, y, pulse), b, a);
```

I don't think you can do anything for eyediagram as it creates a figure not a numeric output.

However, it should be noted that arrayfun is slow see: [arrayfun can be significantly slower than an explicit loop in matlab. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why) and http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/253596 for more details. So you are probably better off just using a loop like you do in the question.

Comment: `arrayfun` does not vectorize; it's just a loop in disguise. In fact, it may be [slower](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why) than a `for` loop.