# MATLAB: How to evaluate a function with multiple inputs on all possible combinations of input vectors

Tags: matlab

Say I have a simple function with three inputs

`f = @(a,b,c) a+b+c`

I would like to evaluate this function on combinations of inputs

```
A = 1:10
B = 2:2:10
C = 0.1:0.1:1
```

and store the output in a matrix `F`.

Right now I am doing this as follows:

```
F = NaN(length(A),length(B),length(C));

for ia = 1:length(A)
   for ib = 1:length(B)
     for ic = 1:length(C)
        F(ia,ib,ic) = f(A(ia),B(ib),C(ic))
     end
   end
end
```

I am wondering if there is an efficient way to do this without the use of sloppy for loops, *and without having to vectorize the function `f`.

Comment: Getting rid of the loops and vectorizing `f` are eseentiallythe same thing, as I see it. You could use `bsxfun` with a custom non-vectorized function, but I doubt it will be faster than loops

Comment: You can use `meshgrid` for `A,B,C` then use just one loop. It is not efficient but might look smarter!

Comment: @LuisMendo How? Speed isn't an issue this time, I just wanted cleaner syntax :-)

Comment: @Kamtal Could you use `meshgrid` and `bsxfun` together?

Comment: @knedlsepp Whoops! Thanks for pointing this out. I just fixed it.

Comment: @BerkU. I mean something like `f = @(a,b) a+b; A = 1:10; B = 2:2:10; resultAB = bsxfun(f, A(:), B(:).');`.  But it only works for two variables
`

Comment: Why would you want to do that if not for speed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want neat syntax and don't care much about memory or speed, you can use:

1. [`ndgrid`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) to generate all combinations; and then
2. [`arrayfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) to call `f` on each combination:

The second step exploits the fact that `arrayfun` can be called with *several* arrays as input, and in that case it takes corresponding elements from each array:

```
[aa, bb, cc] = ndgrid(A,B,C);        %// step 1
result = arrayfun(f, aa, bb, cc);    %// step 2
```

As for the memory and speed concerns I mentioned above:

- Step 1 requires quite a lot of *memory* if the input vectors are large, because all combinations are generated at once.
- Step 2 may result in code *slower* than using `for` loops; see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why).