# Using a matrix as a index to perform functions on another - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have two matrices in this form:

```
ind=
1
1
1
1
2
2
2
2
2
3
3

type = 
A
A
B
A
A
B
A
B
A
B
A
```

I want to be able to identify pairs of a specific kind i.e. A-B and B-A but not A-A. I have been able to do this using IF statements in this form:

```
if strcmp(type(m),'A') == 1 && strcmp(type(m+1),'B') == 1 && ind(m) == ind(m+1)
```

And so forth.

As hinted to within this IF statement, I need to be able to calculate how many valid pairs there are per index.

For example, the first four types `AABA` belong to index '1' because index '1' has a length of 4 as specified in `ind`. Here there are two valid pairs A-B and B-A. A-A is not a valid pair.

The desired output for the full above example would be:

```
2
4
1
```

Is there a quick and easy way to accomplish this?

**EDIT**:

If the types were expanded to include 'C' - and the system needs to detect non-unique pairs i.e. A-B, B-A but also B-B (but nothing containing C) - could this be done? Is there a way to specify which pairs are being counted each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
ind = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3]';  
type = 'AABAABABABA';
accumarray(ind(intersect([strfind(type,'AB'),strfind(type,'BA')],find(~diff(ind)))),1)
```

output:

```
ans =

     2
     4
     1
```

If I recall correctly, `arrayfun` is actually kind of [slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why). I don't think it actually vectorizes the code. Anyway, the idea is to find `'AB'` and `'BA'` with `strfind` and then merge the indices together. However, you cannot count `'AB'` and `'BA'` across index boundaries, so `intersect` with `find(~diff(ind))` will make sure only valid indices are kept. Then `accumarray` will accumulate all the indices together with `ind` for the answer you want.

Comment: Thanks! Very interesting and concise approach. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>> arrayfun(@(x) sum(diff(type(ind == x)) ~= 0), unique(ind))

ans =

     2
     4
     1
```

Comment: +1 Very concise. Out of interest, could this be adapted to look for specific pairs? For example if my types were expanded to A/B/C and I wanted to find A-B, B-A and B-B (thus a non-unique pair) but nothing containing C, could this be done?