# Using Cellfun to perform function upon a single array multiple times

Tags: matlab

I wish to use cellfun similarly to how I would use bsxfun for applying a function on nx1 cell and 1x1 cell i.e for bsxfun,

```
multi = bsxfun(@times, rand(1,10), 2)
```

However, when doing something like this in cellfun it complains that the cells are not the same size. How can I resolve this?

To use for a Cell Example:

My actual problem is pretty simple and I can see some other ways around this but my initial instincts were to use cellfun. Not being able brought me here. Here is my actual problem,

```
use_var = {[0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0]}; rule_dep = {[1,3],[1,2,4],[3,5,7],[5],[4,8]};
```

I now wish to indexuse_var by each individual rule_dep. My first try was,

```
use_rule = cellfun(@(x,y) y{x}, rule_depend, use_var, 'Uniformoutput', false);
```

but throws up dimension problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to define a function handle which returns the expected result for any element of `rule_dep`

```
use_var = [0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0] %must be a array, not cell
use_rule = cellfun(@(x) use_var(x), rule_dep,  'Uniformoutput', false)
```

Something like singleton dimension expansion is not available in cellfun. Keep it mind that [cellfun and arrayfun are often slower than a for-loop.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why) The best solution might be a simple loop.

Comment: This worked beautifully, thank you. I was not aware of the potential speed difference. I have already written a one line loop so shall time both in this instance and see which is fastest.

Comment: cellfun - Elapsed time is 0.009932 seconds.
loop - Elapsed time is 0.010384 seconds.
I guess it makes the difference on larger matrices.