# Optimization of part of code in matlab (better performance)

Tags: matlab, optimization

first of all take my appoligy for my bad english.

I am trying to optimize par of my code using cellfun. (Now I know cellfun is not going to optimize perfomance, just shorten the code).

```
l = [1,20,10,1];
for k=1:length(edg)
    e = edg{k};
    d = lineSegmentIntersect(l, e);
    d2 = lineSegmentIntersect([l(3) l(4) l(1) l(2)], e);
    if d.intAdjacencyMatrix
        if d.intMatrixX == e(1) && d.intMatrixY == e(2) ||  d.intMatrixX == e(3) && d.intMatrixY == e(4)
        else
            it = 1; 
            break;
        end
    elseif d2.intAdjacencyMatrix  
        if d2.intMatrixX == e(1) && d2.intMatrixY == e(2) ||  d2.intMatrixX == e(3) && d2.intMatrixY == e(4)
        else
            it = 1;
            break;
        end
    end
end
```

I mannaged to calc lineSegmentIntersect for each l,edg pair,

```
d = cellfun(@(x) lineSegmentIntersect(x,l),edg);
d2 = cellfun(@(x) lineSegmentIntersect(x,[l(3) l(4) l(1) l(2)]),edg);
```

but I cannot find any information on how to use conditions inside the cellfun. Is it even possible? (this is not relevant anymore)

If not, **is there any other way of optimizing this?**

Function lineSegmentIntersect returns a struct, from which I am using 3 properties for my conditions:

- intAdjencyMatrix (if 1 the segments intersects)
- intMatrixX (x coordinate of the intersection)
- intMatrixY (y coordinate of the intersection)

If l intersects one of the edg, than I want to return 1.

Would be realy greatful for any hints.

UPDATE: I tried to use vectorization but I cannot find a similar case, or this one is just to complex for vectorization?.

Thanks alot!

Comment: What conditions are you trying to use? Could you also post your function `lineSegmentIntersect`?

Comment: [arrayfun and cellfun is not faster than a for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why), it just results in shorter code.

Comment: @Daniel thank you for sharing that, I realy need to optimize my performance. Do you have any suggestion on how to? Thanks!

Comment: @Tim Adams the conditions are visible in the code above the cellfun, the if else segment to be precise. I want to use them with the result of lineSegmentIntersect function

Comment: @bonbonvoyage: Without being able to run the code and run it, I can't give any advice.

Comment: @Daniel You can find lineSegmentIntersect code [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27205-fast-line-segment-intersection/content/lineSegmentIntersect.m). Example of edg: edg = {[1,10,11,2],[1,50,11,2],[1,10,21,2]}