# Creating a function handle for each element in a vector (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, vector, function-handle

I have a following issue. I am trying to create a function handle, which is a vector. In particular, I have something like this

```
    EQ0 = @(W) m1.^2*(exp(W))-m2.^2
```

where m1 and m2 are the vectors of the same dimension. So, for each m1(i) and m2(i) I want to have a handle W(i). I need it in order to find those W(i)'s in the next step using fsolve in something looking like this

```
    n=size(m1)        
    x0 = zeros(n);
    Wbar = fsolve(EQ0,x0)
```

I have tried using arrayfun, but received a following error

```
   EQ0 = arrayfun( @(W) m1.^2*(exp(W))-m2.^2, m1=m1e, m2=m2e)
   Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign is not a valid target for an assignment.
```

Another attempt in using arrayfun resulted in this (here I just used m1 and m2 vectors directly, not as an inputs like in previous case)

```
    EQ0 = arrayfun( @(W) m1.^2*(exp(W))-m2.^2,:)
    Undefined variable arrayfun.
```

I am clearly missing something. I have looked on some feeds on arrayfun but it looks like my problem is somewhat different.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: isnt the function handle rather EQ0 than W? if looping an option here, so that you would have EQ0(1:10) and x0(1:10) and the loop through the 10 different?

Comment: This is **not** Python.  `m1=m1e` and `m2=m2e` is not correct syntax.

Comment: @Finn My sole objective here is to eventually solve a system of independent non-linear equations for W. I define a function f(W, m1, m2, ...) where W would be a matrix input (n x m), and then I want to assign a handle to operate this matrix W, in order to be able to use fsolve to find those Ws (think of fixed-point problem for each entry of this (n x m) matrix)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I understood you right you want to have for each m1(i) or m2(i) a seperate function handle EQ0(i) which can operate with an vector W in the following way EQ0(i) = @(W) m1(i)^2*(exp(W))-m2(i)^2. Is this correct? If so you can create a cell-array of the same dimension as m1 with a function handle in each dimension:

```
EQ0 = cell(size(m1));
for ii = 1:numel(m1)
   EQ0(ii) = {@(W) m1(ii)^2*exp(W)-m2(ii)^2};
end
```

EDIT:
Another option could be:

```
EQ0 = @(W)arrayfun(@(Wel,m1el,m2el)m1el^2*exp(Wel)-m2el^2,W,m1,m2);
fsolve(EQ0, W_Values)
```

Here m1, m2 should be defined beforehand. Otherwise you have to add them as arguments of the first anonymous function.
So by calling `arrayfun(@(Wel, m1el, m2el)..., W, m1, m2)` you do your elementwise calculations for the entries in `W, m1, m2` defined by the anonymous function handle you have passed in the first argument of arrayfun. But since you want to define your `W` differently each time, you make an anonymous function of that arrayfun command, which takes `W` as an argument.

Comment: This seems to be a solution to the problem. If there is a way to do it without loops, I would like to know how for the future (if it means being faster).

Comment: Just a comment: even though the thing above works, since doing above in a loop and then applying fsolve in a loop (my matrices have over 100,000 individual entries) is quite inefficient. Still waiting for a code to finish running....

Comment: Ah ok I think what you are looking for is something like the thing I've edited?

Comment: Yes. The edited version is much more useful for large sets of data since it avoids loops.

Comment: Careful. `arrayfun` is still technically a loop.

Comment: @rayryeng So you mean arrayfun is not paralellized?

Comment: Exactly... unless you use gpuArrays

Comment: Ah I found some interesting post about this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why)

Thanks for pointing this out!