# MATLAB: Multiply 2D matrix with 3D matrix within cell arrays

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, cell-array, multiplication

I have a constant 2D double matrix `mat1`. I also have a 2D cell array `mat2` where every cell contains a 2D or 3D double matrix. These double matrices have the same number of rows and columns as `mat1`. I need to dot multiply (.*) `mat1` with every slice of each double matrix within `mat2`. The result needs to be another cell array `results` with the same size as `mat2`, whereby the contatining double matrices must equal the double matrices of `mat2` in terms of size.

Here's my code to generate `mat1` and `mat2` for illustrating purposes. I am struggling at the point where the multiplication should take place.

```
rowCells = 5;
colCells = 3;
rowTimeSeries = 300;
colTimeSeries = 5;
slices = [1;10];

% Create 2D double matrix
mat1 = rand(rowTimeSeries, colTimeSeries);

% Create 2D cell matrix comprisiong 2D and/or 3D double matrices
mat2 = cell(rowCells,colCells);

for c = 1:colCells
    for r = 1:rowCells
        slice = randsample(slices, 1, true);
        mat2{r,c} = rand(rowTimeSeries, colTimeSeries, slice);
    end
end

% Multiply (.*) mat1 with mat2 (every slice)

results = cell(rowCells,colCells);

for c = 1:colCells
    for r = 1:rowCells
        results{r,c} = ... % I am struggling here!!!
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`bsxfun`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to remove the need for your custom function `multiply2D3D`, it works in a similar way! Updated code:

```
results = cell(rowCells,colCells);
for c = 1:colCells
    for r = 1:rowCells
        results{r,c} = bsxfun(@times, mat1, mat2{r,c});
    end
end
```

This will work for 2D and 3D matrices where the number of rows and cols is the same in each of your "slices", so it should work in your case.

---

You also don't need to loop over the rows and the columns of your cell array separately. This loop has the same number of iterations, but it is one loop not two, so the code is a little more streamlined:

```
results = cell(size(mat2));
for n = 1:numel(mat2)   % Loop over every element of mat2. numel(mat2) = rowCells*colCells
    results{n} = bsxfun(@times, mat1, mat2{n});
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had almost the exact same answer as Wolfie but he beat me to it.

Anyway, here is a one liner that I think is slightly nicer:

```
nR = rowCells; % Number of Rows
nC = colCells; % Number of Cols
results = arrayfun(@(I) bsxfun(@times, mat1, mat2{I}), reshape(1:nR*nC,[],nC), 'un',0);
```

This uses [`arrayfun`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) to perform the loop indexing and [`bsxfun`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) for the multiplications.

---

**A few advantages**

1) Specifying `'UniformOutput'` (`'un'`) in [`arrayfun`](http://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) returns a cell array so the `results` variable is also a cell array and doesn't need to be initialised (in contrast to using loops).

2) The dimensions of the indexes determine the dimensions of `results` at the output, so they can match what you like.

3) The single line can be used directly as an input argument to a function.

**Disadvantage**

1) [Can run slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why) than using `for` loops as Wolfie pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Good answer / code Jacob, I hadn't thought of using `arrayfun`! Maybe worth noting a *disadvantage* too though. I've just done some testing, and it appears that using `arrayfun` is slower than just looping for a variety of sizes for the inputs. See this SO question, the top answer for which goes into a bit of depth about the overheads and speed issues with `arrayfun`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why

Comment: @JacobD Your code is also perfectly working, however, I prefer Wolfie's solution. The main advantage to me is that the code is easier to read and to understand. But that's my personal opinion.

Comment: @Wolfie Good point, I forgot add something about the speed/overhead with `arrayfun`. For small sizes it may not be an issue but scaled up yes, definitely could waste some time. I'd imagine the speed difference between using `arrayfun` or `for` loops in this scenario would depend strongly on the ratio of the 'inner' and 'outer' matrix sizes (`Cells` vs `TimeSeries` as the OP put it).

Comment: @Andi That is completely understandable, `for` loops quite reguarly provide easier code to read/understand. Often in Matlab, though, `for` loops slow the computation and so matrix manipulation can be preferred. This solution is perhaps aimed more to that point, even if it is slower because of `arrayfun`, it at least shows a solution without the `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I came up with is to outsource the multiplication of a 2D with a 3D matrix into a function. However, I am curious to know whether this is the most efficient way to solve this problem?

```
rowCells = 5;
colCells = 3;
rowTimeSeries = 300;
colTimeSeries = 5;
slices = [1;10];

% Create 2D double matrix
mat1 = rand(rowTimeSeries, colTimeSeries);

% Create 2D cell matrix comprisiong 2D and/or 3D double matrices
mat2 = cell(rowCells,colCells);

for c = 1:colCells
    for r = 1:rowCells
        slice = randsample(slices, 1, true);
        mat2{r,c} = rand(rowTimeSeries, colTimeSeries, slice);
    end
end

% Multiply (.*) mat1 with mat2 (every slice)

results = cell(rowCells,colCells);

for c = 1:colCells
    for r = 1:rowCells
        results{r,c} = multiply2D3D(mat1, mat2{r,c});
    end
end


function vout = multiply2D3D(mat2D, mat3D)
%MULTIPLY2D3D multiplies a 2D double matrix with every slice of a 3D
% double matrix.
%
% INPUTs:
%   mat2D:
%   2D double matrix
%
%   mat3D:
%   3D double matrix where the third dimension is equal or greater than 1.
%
% OUTPUT:
%   vout:
%   3D double matrix with the same size as mat3D. Every slice in vout
%   is the result of a multiplication of mat2D with every individual slice
%   of mat3D.

[rows, cols,  slices] = size(mat3D);
vout = zeros(rows, cols, slices);

for s = 1 : slices
    vout(:,:,s) = mat2D .* mat3D(:,:,s);
end

end
```