# Vectorizing logic to check if index matches

Tags: matlab, math, octave, vectorization

I have the following function that works perfectly, but I would like to apply vectorization to it...

```
for i = 1:size(centroids,1)
    centroids(i, :) = mean(X(idx == i, :));
end
```

It checks if `idx` matches the current index and if it does, it calculates the `mean` value for all the `X` values that correspond to that index.

This is my attempt at vectorization, my solution does not work and I know why...

```
centroids = mean(X(idx == [1:size(centroids,1)], :));
```

The following `idx == [1:size(centroids,1)]` breaks the code. I have no idea how to check if `idx` equals to either of the numbers from `1` to `size(centroids,1)`.

**tl:dr**

Get rid of the for loop through vectorization

Comment: Can you give an example of your X vector

Comment: Actually, the for loop is redundant here. The value of idx will be equal to i only once. You can just use this line to accomplish that `centroids(idx, :) = mean(X(idx, :));`. However, in case you want to do something different, which by the way is not clear from your question, you should provide an example of values of `X` and the desired output for `centroids`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can split the matrix into cells and take the mean from each cell using `cellfun` (which applies a loop in its inner operation):

generate data:

```
dim = 10;
N = 400;
nc = 20;
idx = randi(nc,[N 1]);
X = rand(N,dim);
centroids = zeros(nc,dim);
```

mean using loop (the question's method)

```
for i = 1:size(centroids,1)
    centroids(i, :) = mean(X(idx == i, :));
end
```

vectorizing:

```
% split X into cells by idx
A = accumarray(idx, (1:N)', [nc,1], @(i) {X(i,:)});
% mean of each cell
C = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) mean(x,1),A,'UniformOutput',0));
```

maximum absolute error between the methods:

```
max(abs(C(:) - centroids(:))) % about 1e-16
```

Comment: sorry, did not see your answer before I posted mine. Upvoted for you, as you were the first to answer.

Comment: It's fine, they're similar but not identical, so it's best to have a variety of answers.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use `arrayfun`;

```
nIdx      = size(centroids,1);
centroids = arrayfun(@(ii) mean(X(idx==ii,:)),1:nIdx, 'UniformOutput', false);
centroids = vertcat(centroids{:})
```

Since the output of a single function call is not necessarily a scalar, the `UniformOutput` option has to be set to `false`. Thus, `arrayfun` returns a cell array and you need to `vertcat` it to get the desired double array.

Comment: `arrayfun` has more or less the same performance as an explicit loop; it doesn't really count as vectorization

Comment: Well, arrayfun is a built-in function, i.e. pre-compiled. In my experience it gives you better performance than an explicit loop.

Comment: It depends on the specific case and on the Matlab version, but generally `arrayfun` [is](https://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/324130-is-arrayfun-faster-much-more-than-for-loop) (or [used](http://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/260563) to be) [slower](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522888/arrayfun-can-be-significantly-slower-than-an-explicit-loop-in-matlab-why)