# Is Matlab's arrayfun operation more memory-efficient than a pre-allocated for loop?

Tags: matlab, memory

For example, would

```
raw = ones(1000, 1);
x = cell(1000, 1);
for i=1:size(raw, 1)
    x(i) = some_process(raw(i));
end
```

require more memory than

```
raw = ones(1000, 1);
x = arrayfun(@(r) some_process(r), raw, 'UniformOutput', False);
```

As far as my understanding goes, the pre-allocated for-loop would require initialization of both
raw and x before beginning the process thus requiring more memory overall. Is this correct?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [Closely related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12522888/2586922)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not more efficient, and in some cases may even perform worse. `arrayfun` is basically just syntactic sugar for a `for` loop. Matlab's JIT is able to optimize "in-place" modifications of preallocated arrays. I have not encountered any cases where `arrayfun()` used with a function handle performs better than a `for` loop and preallocated arrays on recent-ish versions of Matlab.

In your particular case, they're likely to perform about the same. So use whichever style you prefer.

Note that, strictly speaking, `arrayfun` does *not* perform "vectorized" operations. "vectorized" refers to some built-in Matlab facility that is able to operate on a whole array inside the Matlab engine, using . `arrayfun` isn't able to magically do that.

Exception: if you are using the Matlab Parallel Computing Toolbox, or are operating on `tall` arrays, then `arrayfun` actually can parallelize operations across multiple array elements, and may go faster than a for loop.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is a great answer. Could I essentially say that for loops are the way to go unless parallelization is a requirement - as they're faster and perform similarly on memory to arrayfun?

Comment: Yes. :) And they're more readable, too, in my opinion.